# When Would You Prefer DateTime Over DateTimeOffset

Tags: .net, datetime, datetimeoffset

A few months ago I was introduced to the new [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) type and was glad [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.aspx)'s flaws with regard to time zones were finally taken care of.

However, I was left wondering if there were any overhead or problems that could occur from using this new type.

I work on a multi-locale web application. Does anyone know of anything that could sway me from just using it for all my date/time work? Is there a window for abuse here?

Reference: [DateTimeOffset: A New DateTime Structure in .NET 3.5 by Justin Van Patten](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2007/06/14/datetimeoffset-a-new-datetime-structure-in-net-3-5-justin-van-patten.aspx)

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14268167)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset)

Comment: That link doesn't take me to the article. This one does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bclteam/datetimeoffset-a-new-datetime-structure-in-net-3-5-justin-van-patten

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Sometimes you really just want to represent a "local" (timezone unaware) date and time rather than an *instant* in time. To be honest it's more often useful to represent just a time - e.g. "wake me up at 8am, regardless of timezone" - but date and time could be useful too.

I agree that for the vast majority of cases, `DateTimeOffset` is a better fit. It does strike me as odd that there isn't a `DateTimeTimeZone` struct which has both the instant and its timezone though... an offset doesn't actually give you all the information you need. (For instance, given a `DateTimeOffset`, you don't know what the time will be 24 hours later, because you don't know when DST might kick in.)

If you want that kind of structure, I have a [very crude implementation in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-fx-35#246529). I'm sure it could be improved very easily :)

Comment: You could always represent your times in UTC and convert to a specific time zone when needed...

Comment: Omer: But often you want to preserve the timezone information as well, I find. Yes, often you can get away with just the UTC time, but for recurrent events and the like you need to know the timezone too.

Comment: Local time should usually only be used for future dates, where you want them to adjust with timezone changes. Historical data should always be stored in a consistent time zone, probably UTC though there may be historical reasons for another. (Example: for NYSE transactions data you might want EST across the board).

Comment: @Ben: You're thinking about *instants* in time though. Not everything is like that. For example, "my birthday" is June 19th, every year - past, present and future. Or "the first day of the year 2000", which started at a different instant in each time zone. Or "6am" of my alarm clock. Basically it's worth making sure you know what kind of thing you're really representing.

Answer (score 3):

Well, one obvious answer would be when you need to support clients without the SP that it ships in (it isn't actually in 3.5 - it is in 2.0 SP1, which shipped at the same time).

Comment: True, but I was actually talking about internally in my code and in the UI layer.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought I'd mention it because VS multi-targetting doesn't make it obvious when you've used SP1 features while allegedly targetting 2.0. There is now an FxCop (etc) add-in to do this, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I wouldn't PREFER to use DateTime over DateTimeOffset, please note that sometimes you NEED to, as MS .Net does not support DateTimeOffset as a DataColumn.DataType property [DataColumn.DataType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=netframework-4.7.2) even though SQL datetimeoffset has been around since SQL2008.

I myself had a problem with reading (`ReadXml`) a DateTimeOffset value of an XML exported DataSet with `XmlReadMode.InferTypedSchema`; it read it as a DateTime and crashed when I tried to merge it into a DateTimeOffset column