# How do I calculate the difference of times from three text boxes?

Tags: c#, date, time

I have three text boxes where I can enter time like on this screenshot:

[image: Form screenshot]

Finally I want to get the difference of entry time (t1), exit time (t2) and break (t3): t1 - t2 - t3.

But I am not able to do that because of error message:

> Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan' and 'System.DateTime'

My code is as follows:

```
DateTime t1, t2, t3,  reserve;
t1 = DateTime.Parse(inBox.Text); //from text box1 eg.11:30
t2 = DateTime.Parse(outBox.Text); //from text box2 eg.12:30
t3 = DateTime.Parse(breakBox.Text); //from text box3 eg.0:30
TimeSpan diffTime = t2 - t1 -t3;// there is a problem doing this!!!
answerLabel.Text = diffTime.ToString();
```

Comment: witch error message do you get?

Comment: You can't subtract a DateTime from a TimeSpan.

Comment: Is DateTime really the way you want to go with this? You would be better using TimeSpan throughout as far as I can see.

Comment: What do you mean by the difference of three times?

Comment: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.TimeSpan' and 'System.DateTime'

Comment: One Note: TimeSpan difftTime =t2-t1; is possible however.

Comment: [link]http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=8910b6a

Comment: If you have additional information that goes with your question, edit the question to include that information instead of giving us links.

Comment: What would that mean in practice?  Your wall clock can show 12, 10 and 6 o'clock.  What is 12 - 10 - 6 supposed to mean?  -4 is of course nonsense, avoid doing nonsensical things and your compiler will not tell you it is nonsense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hours elapsed between two times, irrespective of country and time zones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718614/hours-elapsed-between-two-times-irrespective-of-country-and-time-zones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the screenshot you provided in the link I think you are looking for this:

```
DateTime entryTime = DateTime.Parse("11:30");
DateTime exitTime = DateTime.Parse("14:30");
TimeSpan breakSpan = TimeSpan.Parse("0:30");
TimeSpan workSpan = (exitTime - entryTime - breakSpan);
answerLabel.Text = workSpan.ToString();
```

The break must not be a `DateTime` but a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: You may accept this as an answer ;-)

Comment: I edited your question. When you ask next time take it as an example ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
DateTime t1, t2, t3,  reserve;

t1 = DateTime.Parse(inBox.Text); //from text box1 eg.11:30
t2 = DateTime.Parse(outBox.Text); //from text box2 eg.12:30
t3 = DateTime.Parse(breakBox.Text); //from text box3 eg.0:30

TimeSpan diffTime1 = t1 - t2;
TimeSpan diffTime2 = t2 - t3;

TimeSpan totalSpan = diffTime1 + diffTime2;

answerLabel.Text = diffTime2.ToString();
```

Comment: This won't work because the break must be a `TimeSpan` and not a `DateTime` and the break cannot be added it must be subtracted.