# Which C# datatype should be used to store dates without time?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

There is a data type for storing dates without time in `PostgreSQL`. What is the best data type for storing dates without time in C#?

We know, `DateTime` can be used with 00:00:00 time, but this is very misleading for external users and dates also doesn't have time zones, but `DateTime` does. NodaTime cannot be used in our project, so we are looking for a native `.NET` solution.

Comment: How will your "external users" read the dates? I'd say use ISO 8601 format without time. So use DateTime internally, and print them as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: @CodeCaster this isn't a display only issue. Comparing dates for example should *not* force you to convert everything to the same timezone. This is a *real* pain in travel-related applications. Equally, comparing times should *not* force you to use some arbitrary date as base.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know very well about the timezone and time problems of the BCL's `DateTime` structure, but I don't see OP talking about timezones. While a lot of software does now or in the future need to deal with timezones, if OP's dates are all in the same timezone and always will be, using DateTime with a time part of "00:00" won't harm anyone. The only problem OP is having is with the displaying/exporting part, to which I suggested a solution with a question - which OP did not answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster the OP does mention timezones and they *do* affect conversions and comparisons - unless *all* dates are UTC, even those eg retrieved from input parameters in an MVC action or retrieved from `date` fields in SQL Server, there will be unexpected timezone conversions when you compare values with different DateTimeKind.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I referred to _"doesn't have time zones"_, i.e. all dates are in the same timezone. Of course a warning is in place, but given the constraints it seems like you're addressing a non-issue and `System.DateTime` is fine here. When comparing DateTimes of different kinds, you [don't need to convert them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930489/). Yes, using DateTime has its caveats, but it's not as unusable as you seem to be claiming. If all OP wants is to output a date, `DateTime.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD")` _can_ be a viable solution.

Comment: Late to the party but I agree with CodeCaster. If you are simply representing a Date and not doing any time-zone manipulation, DateTime is fine and should be the recommended solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DateTime doesn't have timezone info, only a generic UTC/"Local" indicator.

There is no date- or time-only type in .NET at the time. While the lack of `Date` is an inconvenience, the lack of `TimeOfDay` is a bigger problem. People are experimenting with Date and TimeOfDay types though at the [CoreFX Lab](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab) repository.

At the moment you'll have to use the `DateTime` class or create your own `Date` class. Even the SQL Server ADO.NET provider doesn provide a date or time only class.

Of course you can always "borrow" the MIT-licensed [experimental Date implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/master/src/System.Time/System/Date.cs) from CoreFX Lab.

**NOTE**

I understand the pain and the need as I work on air travel related software. Having to work with timezones when I only want to compare against a date is really tiresome. Things begin to really ---- though when I need to convert between Json and DateTime to pass date only values.

Comment: Since I didn't know about CoreFX Lab and I appreciate your detailed explanation (+1).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any data type that would suit your needs in .NET.

There is only the `DateTime` struct that holds a value for a date and time.

Furthermore, I don't see the reason why don't you use the `DateTime` and show only the date to the users.

Comment: Microsoft does this as well with their SQL Server implementation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Using DateTime is *not* optimal for date- or time-only values. Travel dates for example should *not* have to be converted to UTC to compare. There are many situations where one has to perform timezone conversions just to compare two dates

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure thing but I just wanted to pointed out that this is the situation in .NET, unless your resort to the usage of a library like NodaTime, where comparisons (and generally) are far more easier. Personally, I had the to face with a problem of converting one DateTime to another DateTime in another TimeZone. For my goodness , I knew that the DateTime was in UTC and the things gone a bit easier, using NodaTime. When I was reading the DateTime from the DB, it's Kind was unspecified and I had first to create a DateTime with a UTC specified Kind...before I proceeded with the rest.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Generally, DateTime's are a bit hard to be manipulated as they had be designed in .NET. Fortunately, NodaTime address this issue. Ευχαριστώ (Thanks) for your comment.