# Cleanest way to check if a date is in a range (Nullable Date)

Tags: c#

What is the cleanest way to check if a supplied date is in a given date range?
For example:

```
DateTime? maxDate
DateTime? minDate
DateTime? userDate
```

I want to check if the userDate is in the range.  Where min or max can be null.

So for example:

```
minDate = new DateTime(2017, 1, 1);
maxDate = null;
userDate = new DateTime(2017, 5, 3);
```

In this scenario userDate would be in the range since it's greater then the minDate and no maxDate was specified.

I thought about using DateTime.Compare but it seems that I would create a mess of if/then statements to check userDate to the minDate and maxDate variables since the DateTime.Compare will only compare 2 dates at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `null` min/max would mean 'unbounded' in that direction, you could take advantage of the fact that `DateTime` itself has bounds.

For example:

```
public bool IsDateInRange(DateTime value, DateTime? min, DateTime? max)
{
    //Use provided min/max times if they were not null. Fallback to Min/Max supported values from DateTime
    min = min ?? DateTime.MinValue;
    max = max ?? DateTime.MaxValue;

    return value >= min && value <= max;
}
```

I'm not really sure how you would want to handle the case where `userDate = null`. Is that ever in range? So my example function doesn't allow it. For that case, you could handle it explicitly if you want to define that behavior.

Comment: Good answer.  On a side note, you should [convert to UTC when comparing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930489/safely-comparing-local-and-universal-datetimes) or else you may end up with an incorrect comparison, especially if you are comparing times that fall within the extra hour added or removed for DST,

Comment: To add to this, you could use minDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
  public static bool IsInRange(this DateTime dateToCheck, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
        return (startDate.HasValue && dateToCheck.Date >= startDate.Value.Date) &&
               (endDate.HasValue && dateToCheck.Date <= endDate.Value.Date);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((minDate == null || minDate < userDate) && (maxDate == null || maxDate > userDate)) {
    // Do something
}
```