# Time part of a DateTime Field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime

How would I be able to extract the time part of a DateTime field in SQL? For my  project I have to return data that has a timestamp of 5pm of a DateTime field no matter what the date is

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In SQL Server if you need only the `hh:mi`, you can use:

```
DECLARE @datetime datetime

SELECT @datetime = GETDATE()

SELECT RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(hour, @datetime) as varchar(2)),2) + ':' +
       RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(minute, @datetime)as varchar(2)),2)
```

Comment: @LarryBud i fixed that in an edit - added the RIGHT function calls.

Answer (score 75):

This will return the time-Only

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 108)
```

**Explanation:**

`getDate()` is giving current date and time.
  `108` is formatting/giving us the required portion i.e time in this case.
  `varchar(8)` gives us the number of characters from that portion.
**Like:**
If you wrote `varchar(7)` there, it will give you `00:00:0`
If you wrote `varchar(6)` there, it will give you `00:00:`
If you wrote `varchar(15)` there, it will still give you `00:00:00` because it is giving output of just time portion.
<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/236)</kbd>

<strike>For MySQL:</strike>

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s')
```

<kbd>[<strike>SQLFiddle Demo</strike>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1880)</kbd>

Comment: [visit this](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) for more help.

Answer (score 31):

If you want only the hour of your datetime, then you can use `DATEPART()` - SQL Server:

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '2012-09-10 08:25:53'

select datepart(hour, @dt) -- returns 8
```

In SQL Server 2008+ you can `CAST()` as time:

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '2012-09-10 08:25:53'

select CAST(@dt as time) -- returns 08:25:53
```

Comment: This is great, it enables easy time difference calculations like this:

SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, CAST(@SomeDate AS TIME),CAST(@AnotherDate AS TIME))

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old question, but since the other answers all

- return strings (rather than datetimes),
- rely on the internal representation of dates (conversion to float, int, and back) or
- require SQL Server 2008 or beyond,

I thought I'd add a "pure" option which only requires datetime operations and works with SQL Server 2005+:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -DATEDIFF(dd, 0, mydatetime), mydatetime)
```

This calculates the difference (in whole days) between date zero (1900-01-01) and the given date and then subtracts that number of days from the given date, thereby setting its date component to zero.

Comment: Cool, but with SQL Server 2008 and later it is easier to say `SELECT CAST(mydatetime AS time)` (inferred from other answers).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Unless you are using DATETIMEOFFSET, then CAST(mydatetime AS time) will not work.

Comment: @JumpingJezza Not sure what you mean. I have a table `mytable` with a column `mydatetime` which has the type `(datetime, not null)`, and for me this works fine: `SELECT CAST(mydatetime AS time) AS TimePart, * FROM mytable`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen if your table `mytable` with the column `mydatetime` instead has the type `(DATETIMEOFFSET, not null)` then it will not work. DateTimeOffset is preferred to DateTime in most cases [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4331189/345659)

Comment: @JumpingJezza That is incorrect (at least on my version, SQL Server 2014). It works fine! Surely you lose the time zone in the cast, but that is obvious. I even tried with different "scales", such as `datetimeoffest(0)`, `datetimeoffest(3)`, `datetimeoffest(7)`, etc., and `time(0)`, `time(3)`, `time(7)`, and it works in all cases.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Woops you're right! Actually the error was where I was trying to add it to a date.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I found that if you want to get averages of for example a daily shift finish time, CASTing the DATETIME to TIME will not work since internally SQL Server (I'm using 2019) still seems to keep the datetime representation. You end up getting what looks like an average of the DATETIME value, and not the TIME only component. By setting all the date parts to be the same, averaging the time will work. Also note that if you look at the output of the SELECT, the "zero" date component part will display as the start of the date epoch, i.e.,  '1900-01-01'.

Answer (score 8):

Try this in SQL Server 2008:

```
select *
from some_table t
where convert(time,t.some_datetime_column) = '5pm'
```

If you want take a random datetime value and adjust it so the time component is 5pm, then in SQL Server 2008 there are a number of ways. First you need start-of-day (e.g., 2011-09-30 00:00:00.000).

- One technique that works for all versions of Microsoft SQL Server as well as all versions of Sybase is to use `convert/3` to convert the datetime value to a varchar that lacks a time component and then back into a datetime value:

  ```
  select convert(datetime,convert(varchar,current_timestamp,112),112)
  ```

The above gives you start-of-day for the current day.

- In SQL Server 2008, though, you can say something like this:

  ```
  select start_of_day =               t.some_datetime_column
                      - convert(time, t.some_datetime_column ) ,
  from some_table t
  ```

  which is likely faster.

Once you have start-of-day, getting to 5pm is easy. Just add 17 hours to your start-of-day value:

```
select five_pm = dateadd(hour,17, t.some_datetime_column
                   - convert(time,t.some_datetime_column)
                   )
from some_table t
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that from MS SQL 2012 onwards you can use `FORMAT(value,'format')`

e.g. `WHERE FORMAT(YourDatetime,'HH:mm') = '17:00'`

Comment: ... but do try it for performance, because I've just experienced FORMAT() being astonishingly slow, sadly, like 2 mins vs 5 secs with or without a date format on just 100 rows. Puzzling because I've never had that issue before.

Answer (score 2):

"For my project, I have to return data that has a timestamp of 5pm of a DateTime field, No matter what the date is."

So I think what you meant was that you needed the date, not the time. You can do something like this to get a date with 5:00 as the time:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GetDate(), 110) + ' 05:00:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should strip away the date part:

```
select convert(datetime,convert(float, getdate()) - convert(int,getdate())), getdate()
```

and return a datetime with a default date of 1900-01-01.

Comment: second expression ROUND UP date, need use `floor(convert(float))` , not `convert(int)`

`convert(datetime,convert(float,ok_date_added) -floor(convert(float,ok_date_added)))`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE())` in this case:

```
INSERT INTO infoTbl
(itDate, itTime)
VALUES (GETDATE(),CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()))
```

or if you want print it or return that time use like this:

```
DECLARE @dt TIME
SET @dt = CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE())
PRINT @dt
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'm surprised this wasn't given as an answer earlier since the data type has existed since SQL Server 2008, well before the question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

select cast(getdate() as time(0))

returns for example :- 15:19:43

replace getdate() with the date time you want to extract just time from!

Comment: SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) 
without the scale would be more accurate... much better answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT   
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(17), A.SOURCE_DEPARTURE_TIME, 108)  
FROM  
      CONSOLIDATED_LIST AS A  
WHERE   
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(17), A.SOURCE_DEPARTURE_TIME, 108) BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '15:45:00'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @datetime as datetime
set @datetime = getdate()
select cast(cast(@datetime as time) as varchar(8))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation

Answer (score 0):

For year:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, '2021-03-21' );
```

For hour:

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, '2021-03-21 08:50:30' );
```