# Need part of a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008R2.
I am trying to get part of a date in an output, and my column is in `datetime` datatype.
Eg,
If Current date and time is `2016-06-28 17:34:12.060`, then I need output as `17:00` only the Hour with `:00` mins.

I have tried this until now,

```
Select DateName(HH,SUBSTRING('2016-06-28 17:34:12.060',12,5)) +':00'
```

which gives me right output.But when I pass Column Name which is of `datetime` datatype, then it gives error,

```
Select DateName(HH,SUBSTRING(TimeInHour,12,5)) +':00'
```

gives error,

> Argument data type time is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.

I know I am using `SUBSTRING()` at wrong place, But I really don't know how to achieve that output.
A help will be much appreciable.I need output as HH:00, Hour will be anything but 00 mins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time part of a DateTime Field in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354699/time-part-of-a-datetime-field-in-sql)

Comment: yup possibly but not exactly

Comment: There are a couple of options.  You can [cast](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx) from one data type to another.  Or you can make sure of SQL Server's [date and time functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186724.aspx).

Comment: ...or you can make **use** of SQL Server's data and time functions...

Comment: thanks but now its working for me @destination-data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you use `substring()` at all?  The second argument to `datename()` should be a date/time data type.  So, just do:

```
Select DateName(hour, '2016-06-28 17:34:12.060') + ':00'
```

Comment: It works for me fine when I put '2016-06-28 17:34:12.060',but its not exact date.I have a column name TimeInHour which contains list of dates from which I have to get the results.And the column is in datetime datatype

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select CAST(DATEPART(hour,'2016-06-28 17:34:12.060') AS VARCHAR(2)) +':00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that might be helpful

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEPART(YY,'2016-06-28 17:34:12.060')) -- Year
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEPART(mm,'2016-06-28 17:34:12.060')) -- Month
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEPART(d,'2016-06-28 17:34:12.060'))  -- Day   
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEPART(HH,'2016-06-28 17:34:12.060'))+':00' -- Hour
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEPART(mi,'2016-06-28 17:34:12.060'))+':00' -- Minutes
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEPART(ss,'2016-06-28 17:34:12.060')) -- Seconds
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),DATEPART(ms,'2016-06-28 17:34:12.060')) -- Millisecond
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your `DATETIME` type column first, Use <kbd>CAST</kbd> function

```
Select DateName(HH,SUBSTRING(CAST(ColumnName AS VARCHAR(30)),12,5)) +':00'
```

Or alternative to do is Use <kbd>LEFT</kbd> and <kbd>CONVERT</kbd>

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, ColumnName ,108),2)+':00'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(varchar, datepart(hour, getdate())) + ':' + convert(varchar, datepart(second, getdate()))
```