# select only hours from date

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query returns value in this format `2017-11-18 16:00:00.000`

How can i return value in hours only

Desired format

```
16:00:00.000
17:00:00.000
18:00:00.000
```

Query

```
SELECT DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, GetDate()), 0)
```

Comment: this will returns 16:50:16.6800000 i want to returns only hours of the day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time part of a DateTime Field in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354699/time-part-of-a-datetime-field-in-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the value to `time`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, GetDate()), 0))
```

I would be more inclined to write the logic as:

```
SELECT dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, getdate()), cast('00:00' as time))
```

There really is no difference . . . just the logic of adding a certain number of hours to `'00:00'` seems simpler.