# SQL query SELECT time intervals

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, db-browser-sqlite

I'm trying to SELECT all the rows from a SQL database which are between an hour interval, for every day.
The datetime column is called "Dt" and has the following datetime format: 2019-10-17 16:03:43

I'd like to extract all the rows from this table where the Dt was between 22:00:00 and 02:00:00, for everyday.

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE "Dt" BETWEEN '*-*- 22:00:00' AND '*-*- 02:00:00';
```

where * should be any...

Thanks for your support!

EDIT: I forgot to mention: I'm using the integrated SQL interpreter from DB Browser for SQLite

Comment: what rdbms are you using? sql server, oracle, mysql???

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and functions dealing with timestamp (date/time) are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: db-browser-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the time part of the date and compare that it is within the range. Since midnight is between 22 and 2, you will need to split it to two comparisons, time between 22 and 0 and between 0 and 2.

To see how to extract the time take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354699/time-part-of-a-datetime-field-in-sql).

Answer (score 0):

With Postgres, assuming `dt` is defined as `timestamp` you can do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE "Dt" BETWEEN "Dt"::date + time '22:00:00' and ("Dt"::date + 1) + time '02:00:00'
```

Or if you want to exclude timestamps at precisely `02:00:00`

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE "Dt" >= "Dt"::date + time '22:00:00' 
  and "Dt" < ("Dt"::date + 1) + time '02:00:00'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your propsal returns the following: Result: unrecognized token: ":"
At line 1:
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE "Dt" >= "Dt"

Answer (score 0):

```
 select DT_time from (
    select cast (substr(to_char(Dt,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS'),12,2) as integer ) as DT_time from MY_TABLE )
 where  DT_time between 2 and 22;
```

Comment: Result: no such function: to_char

Answer (score 0):

> between 22:00:00 and 02:00:00

means:

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE 
  substr(Dt, 12) BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '23:59:59'
  OR
  substr(Dt, 12) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '02:00:00'
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work ::

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, Dt)>22  
AND DATEPART(HOUR, Dt)<2
```

Update :

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE Dt Between DATEADD (hour,22,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, Dt), 0)) AND DATEADD (hour,2,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, -1, Dt), 0))


SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, Dt)>22  
OR DATEPART(HOUR, Dt)<2
```

Above query work for you..
1st one will check only for particular date and consecutive next date along with your time range.
But If you don't care about dates and only looking for time interval in particular hours then 2nd one is for you.

For SQLite :

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE strftime('%H','Dt')>22  
OR strftime('%H','Dt')<2
```

Comment: The hour can't be greater than 22 and smaller than 2 at the same time. This query will return nothing

Comment: I have just tested sir.. It's working @a_horse_with_no_name
https://imgur.com/a/vYUgHEN

Comment: Well `> 10 AND < 16` is something completely different than `> 22 AND < 2` try the query from your answer, not something different

Comment: I am testing with current time.. If I put 22 AND 2 then it will definitely give 0 results.. cause current time is 12 over here.

Comment: The point is: a single number can not be larger than 22 **and** smaller than 2 at the same time and that's what your answer suggests. Your condition is equivalent to `where 1=2`, see an example here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fdf2aa5eb9397a535b52570348ebc75c

Comment: Yeah I am gettting your point. Will find another solution. Thanks for the knowlege.

Comment: In SQLite there are no DATEPART, DATEADD, DATEDIFF functions.