# how to convert date with 'T' to/from string in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I used following functions to convert `DateTime` from/into `string`:

```
DATE_OBJ.ToString(DATE_FORMAT);

DateTime.ParseExact(Date_string, DATE_FORMAT, null);
```

Now I've got to work with follow format `2012-03-20T14:18:25.000+04:00`

Which format should I use to convert it correctly to `string` and generate `string` like that from `DateTime` object?

Comment: please go through this [Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). It may helps you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can go from DateTime to that format with

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt.ToString("o");
```

and from that format to DateTime with

```
DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateString);
```

Here is some more info on DateTime format:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format

Comment: +1: however, I would advise reading MSDN [The Round-trip ("O", "o") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip)

Answer (score 9):

You are better of using [DateTimeOffSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) like:

```
string str = " 2012-03-20T14:18:25.000+04:00";
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse(str);
//Get the date object from the string. 
DateTime dtObject = dto.DateTime; 

//Convert the DateTimeOffSet to string. 
string newVal = dto.ToString("o");
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this from `DateTime`, as `DateTime` holds no `TimeZone` info.

This is close: `string.Format("{0:s}", dt)` will give `2012-03-20T14:18:25`.
See: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

You could extend this to: `string.Format("{0:s}.{0:fff}", dt)`, which will give `2012-03-20T14:18:25.000`

But you better have a look at `DateTimeOffset`: [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset)

(Not advisable, but to fake it and still use `DateTime`: `string.Format("{0:s}.{0:fff}+04:00", dt)`)

Answer (score -3):

If that is a string you receive then you can split the string by T and use only the first part which is the Date component of the whole string and parse that.

ex:

```
string dateTimeAsString = "2012-03-20T14:18:25.000+04:00";
string dateComponent = dateTimeAsString.Splic('T')[0];
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateComponent, "yyyy-MM-dd",null);
```

Comment: The question is the other way around: DateTime -> String