# json.net returning datetime with T how to not show T

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, json.net

i am really new to Json. I have a datetime (Extracted date) in an object and which has the following value

```
2018-10-10 10:50:00
```

I am using this specific function from Json.net

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object)
```

The returned Json String has letter T in the extracted_date i.e.,

```
{
    "extracted_date": "2018-10-10T10:50:00"
}
```

After research I discovered that it could be to do with ISO Format which Json.net converts the date to. How do I not include the letter in the extracted date? Or is it not possible?

I am using VB.Net and used the following code as per one of the comments and still have the same issue

```
JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newJob, Formatting.Indented,
                                                            New JsonSerializerSettings With
                                                            {.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252634/3201354

Comment: See [Serializing dates in Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) - if none of the default options do what you need, that shows how to write a custom converter which gives you complete control over the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DateFormatString**
Gets or sets how **DateTime** and **DateTimeOffset** values are formatted when writing JSON text, and the expected date format when reading **JSON** text. The default value is **"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFFK"**.

**DateParseHandling**
Gets or sets how date formatted strings, e.g. **"/Date(1198908717056)/"** and **"2012-03-21T05:40Z"**, are parsed when reading **JSON**. The default value is **DateTime**.

> **IsoDateFormat**  Dates are written in the ISO 8601 format, e.g. "**2012-03-21T05:40Z"**.
>
> **MicrosoftDateFormat** Dates are written in the Microsoft JSON format, e.g. "/Date(1198908717056)/".

[look here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm)

```
 JsonConvert.SerializeObject([your object], Formatting.Indented,
                            new JsonSerializerSettings
                            {
                             DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
                            });
```

Comment: While that will probably work, the explanation to set indenting is confusing because it should work with the settings, not the indentation.

Comment: @sinan Baran Thanks for your suggestion, I have tried and still have the issue what am i missing, i am using vb.net by the way. I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the one of the comments I have got it working. My code looks like this, hope this will help someone in future.

```
Dim JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newJob, Formatting.Indented,
                                                            New JsonSerializerSettings With
                                                            {.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
                                                            .DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
                                                            })
```