# How to fix error from formatting a Date from DB

Tags: c#, oop

I've encountered a problem when trying to parse a data from the DB.

The data I have for example is:  `2019-04-19T00:00:00.000Z`

I'm trying to get it to the format of `dd/MM/yyyy` but I'm encountering the error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Here's my code block

```
string x = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-04-19T00:00:00.000Z","'\"'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z\"'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Am I specifying the wrong format? Or are there any other ways of doings this?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse("2019-04-19T00:00:00.000Z").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert date with 'T' to/from string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252312/how-to-convert-date-with-t-to-from-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string should be `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"` instead for `"'\"'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z\"'"` That is, the code should be like [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/giyr0U)

```
string x = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-04-19T00:00:00.000Z","yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("\"2019-04-19T00:00:00.000Z\"", "'\"'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z\"'", null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

that will give you `19/04/2019`

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
string x = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-04-19T00:00:00.000Z", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd//yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also just parse it -

```
var x = DateTime.Parse("2019-04-19T00:00:00.000Z",
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
     DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```