# How can I pass DateTime format to MS sql server in a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I hope you could help me in my project. 
I have been trying to solve this issue long time ago and it doesn't work.

I'm trying to pass a Date time from c# to MS sql server, note that the server 
stored datetime with format '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'

it's work perfectly when I use it locally, but when I upload page into a server I get error.

```
  string connectionString;
            SqlConnection mySqlConnection;
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[("connectionNamr")].ConnectionString;
           mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand mySqlComd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader reader;
            mySqlComd.CommandText = "ProcedureName";    
            mySqlComd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            mySqlComd.Connection = mySqlConnection;
            SqlParameter depParam = new SqlParameter("@colName1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255);
            SqlParameter empParam = new SqlParameter("@colName2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
            SqlParameter startDateParam = new SqlParameter("@EVcolName3", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            SqlParameter endDateParam = new SqlParameter("@colName4", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            SqlParameter filterParam = new SqlParameter("@colName5", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
            depParam.Value = string.Empty;
            empParam.Value = employeeID;
            DateTime datet = new DateTime(year,month,day);
            string datet1 = datet.ToString();
            //string datet1 = datet.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff'Z'");
           // datet1 = datet1.Substring(0, 19);
            startDateParam.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(datet1.Trim()); ;
            endDateParam.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(datet1.Trim()); ;
            filterParam.Value = string.Empty; 
            mySqlComd.Parameters.Add(depParam);
            mySqlComd.Parameters.Add(empParam);
            mySqlComd.Parameters.Add(startDateParam);
            mySqlComd.Parameters.Add(endDateParam);
            mySqlComd.Parameters.Add(filterParam); 
            mySqlConnection.Open();
            mySqlComd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         reader = mySqlComd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            while (reader.Read())
{
 attendance_date = reader["SITE_IN_TIME"].ToString();
}

            mySqlConnection.Close();
            return attendance_date;

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return "Error, Exception: " + exp;
        }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: When you say that "server stored datetime with format", what do you mean? Is it stored as string?

Comment: @Szymon no it stored as DateTime, which means DateTime format

Comment: @aetheria related to dateTime object

Comment: 1. We will need to know the error you are getting to help diagnose the problem. 2. If the process works locally I would expect a communication error (security / firewall).  3. Is this system going to stay in the same time zone?  Use of DateTime passed from the application tier can lead to issues with "timing".  I would consider DateTimeOffset in your C# code and UTC based times on your SQL database (of type DateTimeOffset).  I generally like to set all timestamps at the database if possible (only have the application pass times that are needed from the user, unless you have a compliance need).

Comment: Side Note: Here is a question and answer on setting time / timezone (if useful).  It may be slightly off topic, but you may find it useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671675/where-to-set-a-utc-datetime-value-in-n-tier-application-presentation-layer-dom

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the date format is because you are converting it to a string and then back to a `DateTime` value. Depending on the culture settings on the specific server this may or may not work. It may also misinterpret the data, e.g. transforming a date from 2013-10-12 to 2013-12-10.

Just use the `DateTime` value that you already have:

```
  DateTime datet = new DateTime(year,month,day);
  startDateParam.Value = datet;
  endDateParam.Value = datet;
```

Side note:

> "note that the server stored datetime with format '1900-01-01
>   00:00:00.000'"

No, it doesn't. A datetime value is a numeric value representing a point in time, it's not stored as text.

Comment: It aslo would be a problem, since it doesn't match server format

Comment: @Alaa12 There's no server format involved at all. `DateTime` data type is binary both in .NET code and SQL Server.

Comment: @Alaa12: When you put the `DateTime` value into the parameter, it doesn't have any format at all, so there is no format that can mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

You can just directly pass `DateTime` to your parameter, there is no need to convert it to string and back to date again:

```
DateTime datet = new DateTime(year,month,day);
startDateParam.Value = datet;
endDateParam.Value = datet;
```