# Best way to store date/time data in SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server Compact 4

Tags: sql-server-2008, timezone, sql-server-ce, datetimeoffset

We are developing an application in C# 4 that uses SQL Server 2008 R2 as backend. SQL Server Compact 4 is also used for disconnected clients in a very few rare scenarios. We are wondering what's the best way to store date/time data into these databases so that:

1. Data containing different time offsets (coming from different time zones) can co-exist nicely. This means being sorted and compared.
2. Data in SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server Compact 4 can be transferred back and forth seamlessly; this is a secondary requirement that should not compromise the chosen design.

Our main concern is to preserve the local time for each recorded event, but without losing the ability to compare and sort events that have been generated from different time zones and therefore have different time offsets.

We have considered the `datetimeoffset` data type, since it stores the time offset and because it maps nicely to .NET's `DateTimeOffset`. However, it is not supported in SQL Server Compact 4. An alternative would be to remove offset info from the database and use a simple `datetime` data type, so that every piece of data in the database is normalized, and the issues with Compact are fewer. However, this introduces the problem that offset info would need to be reconstructed somehow on retrieval before the user sees the data.

So my question is, are there any best practices or guidelines on how to store date/time values in SQL Server, taking into account that we will need to deal with different time zones, and making the interoperability between 2008 R2 and Compact 4 as easy as possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that datetimeoffset doesn't really store a time zone - it *only* stores an offset. That doesn't tell you which time zone it was observed in, i.e. what the local time was 10 minutes later, when the offset *may* have changed. What are these values meant to represent? Just instants in time? Fundamentally, do you need to keep the original offset, or are you only interested in the instant at which something occurred?

Comment: @JonSkeet: You are right; I must admit I hadn't looked at it this way. We are interested in knowing the local time of the event, but also need to be able to compare the time of each event to other events that may have been generated at different places and, therefore, under different time zones (and thus have different offsets).

Comment: Okay - if you *do* need the local time, then you need to store the offset one way or another. Next you need to think about whether you need to be able to *query* this data on local time - for example, you could store a DateTime value in UTC and the offset in a separate column... that would make it easy to order globally, but relatively hard to search locally...

Comment: @JonSkeet: We'd rather optimize for local times than for global comparison/sorting. Perhaps storing DateTime in *local* time, and offset as a separate column? Or, alternatively, DateTimeOffset? Any guidelines/best practices on how well SQL Server's DateTimeOffset works and integrates with .NET?

Comment: The use of SqlServerCE is why I was suggesting not using DateTimeOffset. But yes, you could use a local DateTime and an offset to *subtract* to get the UTC.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thank you. We only use SqlServerCE for disconnected clients in quite rare scenarios, so we wouldn't like to jeopardize our design by paying too much attention to SqlServerCE. :-) We will find a workaround. In other words, most of the work will be done on SQL Server 2008 R2, so that's where we should focus for our design (I'll update my OP on this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the relevant points are:

- Your incoming data is a good fit for `DateTimeOffset`
- You only care about the offset at that particular time, so you don't need a *real* time zone. (An offset isn't a time zone.)
- You *do* care about that original offset - you can't just normalize everything to UTC and ignore the offset entirely.
- You want to query on the *local* time.

It does sound like `DateTimeOffset` is basically the most appropriate type in this case. You should make sure everyone on the team is clear about what it means though - the offset is the offset when the data was originally received. If you want to display that instant in time in a *different* time zone, you effectively need to go back to UTC, and find out what the offset would be in that display time zone. It's easy to get confused about this sort of thing :)

If you need to maintain the data in SqlServerCE with full fidelity, you'll probably want a DateTime field and then a separate field for the offset (e.g. in minutes, or as a TimeSpan if SqlServerCE supports that).

Comment: Thank you; this makes a lot of sense to me. We'll need to find a way around SQL Server CE, but that's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably right to use `DateTimeOffset` on the server.  You might also want to read my answer on [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268167/634824).

On the client, where you are using SQLCE, store a `DateTime` with UTC values.  When you send the data to the server, you can use the local time zone of the client to determine the `DateTimeOffset` that the UTC value corresponds to.

If it's possible that the user might be changing their time zones, then you might also need to store the time zone's id in the client database.  But you would just use this during conversion.  There's no need to send it to the server unless you might be editing those values on the server or in some other client.

Don't try storing the time on the client in the local time of the client.  You will encounter abiguities.  For example, when daylight saving time rolls backwards, you don't want two different possible UTC times for the same local time.

Comment: Thank you for the good tips wrt the client. I am looking at your other answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use datetime and always store the value as a UTC value, then you can format it to the end users (display) time zone when required.

Comment: Well, I'd rather avoid duplicating something that's already implemented by the backend. SQL Server and .NET apparently manage time zones for you with the DateTimeOffset data types. I would only revert to managing them manually, as you suggest, if it had evident benefits.

Comment: Well, SQLCE only supports datetime, so the only other option is to store datetime values in a nchar(34) column, using this formatting: 
dto.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff zzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: ;-) Definitely, the fact that SQLCE does not support datetimeoffset is a good reason to go for an all-over datetime solution and store the offset elsewhere as you suggest. But I would like to explore more options and have some insights on what pros and cons each option would have.