# JsonConvert not converting UTC -> Local time in PopulateObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, timezone, json.net

I have a date coming from javascript via toJSON, so it's stored as a UTC time, but I'd like to store it in the database as local time (we've never stored UTC times in the past, so I need to continue the trend here).

However, setting `DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local` (with version 6.0.0.0 of Newtonsoft.Json) when running `PopulateObject` doesn't do anything, it's still left as a UTC date with the original time.

My question is: why is it not running `dt.ToLocalTime()` which fixes the problem (and is my current workaround) - or: how do I get the converter to do that, if not from the `DateTimeZoneHandling.Local` setting?

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet and a snippet of the json?

Answer (score 5):

Storing a `DateTime` into a database as local time is generally not a great idea, because:

- If your local time zone has [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) rules, then you could potentially be losing data.  During the fall-back transition, there's a one-hour period where a local time could represent two possible moments.  Using UTC avoids this issue.
- It binds your data to a particular location.  If you ever need to migrate your server to another location (or to the cloud), your past data will be inaccurate.

If you *must* store your data in local time, consider storing it as a `DateTimeOffset`.  By recording the offset, you can accurately distinguish the unique point in time it represents, if the local time zone changes.  This adequately counters both of the points above.

See also: [`DateTime` vs `DateTimeOffset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268167/634824).

As to your question about JSON.Net and the `DateTimeZoneHandling.Local` option, this simple example shows that it appears to be working as designed.  I can't reproduce your claim.

```
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var json = "{\"DateTime\":\"2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z\"}";

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
                    };

var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, settings);

Debug.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", foo.DateTime, foo.DateTime.Kind);
```

Output:

```
12/31/2013 16:00:00 (Local)
```

My local time zone is US Pacific Time, which was 8 hours behind UTC on the date provided, which is reflected in the results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am aware of some of the problems with storing GMT, but thanks for not letting me get away with it too easily ;) OK, I'm going to need to get a simpler test case together... Or leave it with the workaround.