# Azure SQL Database DateTime issue

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I have created a simple site using VS2013 and added a DateTime field to the AppUser model.

When testing the site locally using 28/08/2013 the site works fine.

When I deploy to Azure I get an error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Changing the date to 08/28/2013 the site works fine on Azure but not locally.

Can anyone assist with this issue?

Many thanks for taking the time to look

Comment: This isn't a SQL Server issue. You are mixing American and European dates. Just don't use a localized date format, use the [unseparated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.105).aspx#UnseparatedStringFormat) format (20130828) for dates or the [ISO 8601](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.105).aspx#ISO8601Format) format for date+time values.

Comment: Also avoid using raw string statements at all costs. Use parameterized queries to pass strongly-typed parameters and avoid all conversion problems. Parameterized queries are also *much* faster and just as easy to write as strings, if not easier

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of any examples of how best to handle dates with c#?

Answer (score 0):

Well after some searching and many an hour agonising I found that I should be using DateTimeOffSet to handle my dates. I first found that utilising the example of the Identity Previous Pwd implementation I had no issue creating and updating records holding as date. The example can be found [Implementing custom password policy using ASP.NET Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/06/implementing-custom-password-policy-using-asp-net-identity.aspx)

I also found this answer for using DateTimeOffSet:
[Datetime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset)

Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem, hope this helps others.