# How to use TimeSpan in different time zones?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following code that take in input `scheduleConfiguration.Time` in the UTC and return `ticks` in local time.

```
scheduleConfiguration.Time equal {9/13/2015 10:00:00 AM} in UTC

var localTime = scheduleConfiguration.Time.ToLocalTime(); {9/13/2015 1:00:00 PM} in Local
var executionTime = new TimeSpan(localTime.TimeOfDay.Ticks);
```

I changed my data contract `scheduleConfiguration.Time`, so I need to use `TimeSpan TimeOfDay` instead of `DateTime Time`, but I need to have the same `executionTime`. So I do next

```
var local time = DateTime.Now.Date.Add(scheduleConfiguration.TimeOfDay);//{9/13/2015 10:00:00 AM} in Local
var executionTime = new TimeSpan(localTime.Ticks);
```

So I have the difference in 3 hours (and I have UTC +3 time zone)

How to get the same result as for DateTime in the first situation?

Comment: good questions! I think you need to create localTime in the second variant to UTC. So `{9/13/2015 10:00:00 AM}` must be in UTC, not in the local time

Comment: You should check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset

Comment: @Wouter How to use DateTimeOffset in my situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `SpecifyKind` method.

```
var time = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now.Date.Add(span), DateTimeKind.Utc);      
Console.WriteLine(time.ToLocalTime());
```