# Can't bind CalendarDatePicker to a model in Xaml UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I have model class in shared PCL (for android and uwp app) that contain datetime property:

```
public class Meter {
        public int meter_value {get; set; }    
        public DateTime meter_start { get; set; }
        public DateTime meter_end { get; set; }
... other int and string properties
}
```

In MainPage.cs i have

```
public Meter _meter;
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    _meter = new Meter();
}
```

I'm trying to bind this to a xaml controls with following code:

```
   <TextBox 
      Text="{x:Bind _meter.meter_value, Mode=TwoWay}">

   <CalendarDatePicker 
     Name="meter_start"
      Date="{x:Bind _meter.meter_start, Mode=TwoWay}"
      DateFormat="{}{day.integer}/{month.integer}/{year.full}" >
   </CalendarDatePicker>
```

This code produce compile time error: `Invalid binding path '_meter.meter_start' : Cannot bind type 'System.DateTime' to 'System.Nullable(System.DateTimeOffset)' without a converter`

When i change x:Bind to Binding, applicaton compile, but value of meter_start property in my model is 0001/01/01.

Can someone help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the error says you need a converter - [CalendarPicker.Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.date.aspx) is of type `Nullable<DateTimeOffset>` and your property is `DateTime`. Here is a simple example I've tested - in the code:

```
public class TimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return new DateTimeOffset(((DateTime)value).ToUniversalTime());

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return ((DateTimeOffset)value).DateTime;
    }
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:TimeConverter x:Key="TimeConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

... later
<CalendarDatePicker Name="meter_start" Date="{x:Bind _meter.meter_start, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}"
                     DateFormat="{}{day.integer}/{month.integer}/{year.full}"/>
```

You may think of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the *PropertyChanged* event, if you also change the `_meter` from code somewhere.

Note also that when you deal with *DateTime* and *DateTimeOffset*, you need to take care of suitable conversion (time zones etc.). You will find some more info [at this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331189/2681948).

Comment: If i do all of that in my model, will it break android portability of my shared PCL? Meter class is shared between UWP and Android platforms..

Comment: Is this definitely the case? The OP is binding to "_meter.meter_start" which is a property. I see no reason why the parent object has to be a property?

Comment: You are right it doesn't have to be a property, though without RaisingProperty the UI won't know about the change. But the problem is with converter rather than this.