# C# DateTime Serialization with Microsoft Bond

Tags: bond

I was replacing internal Serializations in my application **from Jil to Bond**.

I'm switching simple classes with Ms Bond attributes and everything worked fine until I got one with a **DateTime**.
I had then a **Dictionary KeyNotFound Exception** error during Serialization.

I suspect Bond do not support DateTime, is that so? 
And if it is, why is not implemented? DateTime is not a basic type but adding a custom converter is not worth it, the speed gain vs protobuf-net is minimal and I don't need generics, just simple fast de/serializer.

I hope I'm missing something, I really want to use Bond, but I need an easy tool too, I cannot risk breaking the application because something basic like a Date or Guid is not supported by default.
I'm writing here after hours of researches and the Young Guide to C# bond does not clearly mention what is and what is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no built-in timestamp type in Bond. The built-in types in Bond are documented in the [manual for the gbc compiler](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/compiler.html#struct-definition).

For GUIDs, there's `Bond.GUID`, which has [implicit conversions](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/blob/59be2e21504b2b973108382fd919547d20ea6b39/cs/src/core/Bond.cs#L9-L38) to/from `System.Guid`. Note that `Bond.GUID` lives in bond.bond, so if you want to refer to this from a .bond file, you'll need to [use Bond's import functionality](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cpp/core/import) and `import "bond/core/bond.bond"`

There's an example showing how to use [`DateTime` with a custom type alias](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cs/core/date_time).

The reason there is no built-in timestamp type in Bond is that there are so many different ways (and standards) for representing timestamps. There's a similar [C++ example](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cpp/core/time_alias) that shows representing time with a `boost::posix_time::ptime`, highlighting the various different ways that time is represented.

Our experience has been that projects usually already have a representation for timestamps that they want to use, so, we recommend using a converter so that you can use the representation that's appropriate for your circumstances.

As a side note, my experience has been that [`DateTimeOffset`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset) is a more generally useful type, compared to `DateTime`.