# How to convert this date 2017-07-09T17:50:21.000-0500 | C#

Tags: c#, datetime

when i run the below code, 

`string dt = "2017-07-09T17:50:21.000-0500";
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);`

it gives me output as

> 7/10/2017 4:20:21 AM

where as i want my output to be

> 2017-07-09 17:50

---

***update***

the code @alexander-petrov gave worked 

`string dt = "2017-07-09T17:50:21.000-0500"; 
string date = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dt).DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");`

gives output

> 2017-07-09 17:50

but on inserting the same to database it is adding +5 hrs to the time and inserting as

> 2017-07-09 22:50

Comment: "It is showing wrong time" - what time do you _expect_ it to be?  It's a [standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) - you need to show what you're doing to parse it, and why you think it's different to what it should be.

Comment: 2017-07-09T17:50:21.000-0500 is in string? How are you converting it into DateTime? Can you share that code?

Comment: Probably a problem with timezones. Please post your conversion code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want take offset into account then use `DateTimeOffset` type.

```
string dt = "2017-07-09T17:50:21.000-0500";

DateTimeOffset date = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dt);

// format on my machine
// 09.07.2017 17:50:21 - 05:00
Console.WriteLine(date);

// without offset
// 09.07.2017 17:50:21
Console.WriteLine(date.DateTime);
```

Comment: on converting the same to DateTime result is changing, i need to save // 
// 09.07.2017 17:50 in database

Comment: @stacker - Don't convert to `DateTime`. Always use `DateTimeOffset`. [Must read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331189/5045688).

Comment: the code you gave worked
`string dt = "2017-07-09T17:50:21.000-0500";
string date = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dt).DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");`

gives output >> 2017-07-09 17:50

but on inserting the same to database it is adding 5hrs to the time and inserting as >> 2017-07-09 22:50

Comment: @stacker - ask another question about inserting into database.

Comment: ok..added [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486866/inserting-iso-date-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Round-Trip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip) format of a `DateTime` specified with a `DateTimeKind.Local` kind.
You need to decide if your program needs to be aware of time zones or not.

You could try parsing it while supplying the `System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` or `System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` parameter to the `Parse` method.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your date to work, as I think there is a colon missing in the last part.  Adding that colon back allows me to convert the XSD date time into a SQL DATETIME using this script:

```
DECLARE @stringDate VARCHAR(30);
SELECT @stringDate = '2017-07-09T17:50:21.000-05:00';
DECLARE @xmlDate XML;
SELECT @xmlDate = CAST('' AS XML);
SELECT @xmlDate.value('xs:dateTime(sql:variable("@stringDate"))', 'datetime');
```

Results:

```
2017-07-09 22:50:21.000
```

Comment: The OP doesn't mention SQL in his question or tags.

Comment: _"converting this to c# date time object"_ via calling SQL which transforms the date into XML? Innovative.

Comment: I could have sworn this was a SQL question, my bad ;D

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string date = "2017-07-09T17:50:21.000-0500";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffzzzz", null);
```