# Inserting ISO date in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime

When I run the below code in c#

```
string dt = "2017-07-09T17:50:21.000-0500"; 
string date = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dt).DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

it gives this as output

> 2017-07-09 17:50

but on inserting the same to database it is adding +5 hrs to the time and inserting as

> 2017-07-09 22:50

could someone please help me to insert the same date (2017-07-09 17:50) to database

---

**Update 1**

Here is my complete simplified code

```
DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dTable.Columns.Add("created_on", typeof(DateTime));

foreach (var item in items)
{
DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
dRow["created_on"] = DateTimeOffset.Parse(item.createdon).DateTime;
//-- in item.createdon i get the date like this "2017-07-09T17:50:21.000-0500";
dSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dRow);
}
```

after completing the loop,sending the data to database as xml via stored procedure to insert.

After inserting in database the row is updated with the below date

> > 2017-07-09 22:50

Comment: as you are probably inserting it into a table with a `datetime` column and not as a string, please show the related code. best bet is some time zone conversion issue, but it is difficult to tell with so little information.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Can you tell us what time zone the server is on vs what you are on? What is the data type of the column you are inserting into?

Comment: Can you post your sql code?

Comment: "as xml via stored procedure" > that will be the interesting part. cannot reproduce the problem with the code you gave so far, the documentation of `DateTimeOffset.Parse` specifies that there should be a white space between the parts, but it still works with your sample data, ends up in `dSet` as 2017-07-09 17:50:21.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dlatikay! based on your first comment i changed the datatype from DateTime to string and it worked.

```
dTable.Columns.Add("created_on", typeof(string));
```

When the datatype is DateTime,the result is coming as expected,but on insertion to sql the value is changing.Now, while iam sending the value as string to sql,it is converting that string to DateTime and it worked.

Thank you all for your responses.