# Create a DateTime in a given TimeZone

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to create a `DateTime` object with a fixed value on a given `TimeZone` for today, lets assume it to be `2018-04-23` now I would do `DateTime.Today` or `DateTime.Now.Date` to get it on the local timezone, or I could do `DateTime.UtcNow.Date` to get it on UTC. after that if I want the 9am its something like `DateTime.Today.AddHours(9)` and that would give me `2018-04-23 09:00 am` but that would be, again, on the local timezone, as would `new DateTime(.....)`.

The question then is how could I get `2018-04-23 09:00 am` on a given timezone, lets say PST for instance?

Comment: Relevant: [DateTime vs. DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset)

Comment: @Luiso Let me know if the "duplicate" is totally unsuitable for some reason.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I saw that question/answer before posting my question, and, at least, as far as I could see, it tells you how to create a `DateTime` with timezone information, I want to know how to create any arbitrary `DateTime` value for any given timezone. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't hold any time zone information.  It only tracks a `DateTimeKind` in its `Kind` property.  If you want "now in some other time zone", then take `DateTime.UtcNow` and convert it using the `TimeZoneInfo.Convert...` methods.  Otherwise, please clarify what you're looking to do.

Comment: I found a solution, I got the idea from the Jon Skeet answer to the question above. I needed to have `Today at 9:30 am` no matter the timezone so I created a `DateTime` with the right time, and then `DateTime.SpecifyKind(myDate, unspecified)` and that did the trick. Any other way to go about this?

Comment: Keep in mind that "today" may be different in different time zones at any given moment.  You will need to do something like `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, someTimeZone).Date` to get the base date (instead of `DateTime.Today`).