# How does one find rows created today if the CreatedDate column is of type datetimeoffset?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column named `CreatedDate` of type `DateTimeOffset`, and I need to query to see rows created today.  If this column was of type `DateTime` I would do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE CreatedDate >= GETDATE()
```

How does one accomplish this with a `DateTimeOffset` column, however?

---

Environment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset

Comment: Are you concerned with the current time of day?   Or just today's date?   GETDATE() will return the current time so even as a regular datetime field, that wouldn't get all rows for "today".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the TODATETIMEOFFSET function that is built into SQL Server.

Here is an example of how it is used (-5 is my timezone offset...your usage may vary)...again, this also considers you are only worried about >= current time as your original question suggested.  You would need to adjust usage of GETDATE() if you care about the entire day (see comment on original question).

```
select * from TestingDates d where d.CreatedDate >= TODATETIMEOFFSET(GETDATE(), '-05:00')
```