# Avoiding DateTime conversion while passing it to AspNetCore.SignalR .Net client

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr, msgpack

I am trying to send request from the server to client(.Net) which is running in culture specific environment which affects **dates** to be in special time zone.

I am sending date from the server with Unspecified kind for avoiding it being converted while getting retrieved on client side.  Basically I just convert it like this on server side:

```
DateTime dateToSend = DateTime.SpecifyKind(serverSideDate, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

The problem is that when using *JsonProtocol* for the client, date is not getting converted and is getting processed correctly, while for *MessagePackProtocol* the same code for client and server side works completely different way - it converts date to culture specific timezone on the client...

How to prevent that conversion, without some hack solutions like passing date as a string.

**UPDATE:**
As Shaun suggested, I've configured MessagePack both on client and server side this way, but unfortunaly it's still not working:

```
.AddMessagePackProtocol(options =>
    options.FormatterResolvers = new List<MessagePack.IFormatterResolver>()
    {
        StandardResolver.Instance,
        NativeDateTimeResolver.Instance
    })
```

Comment: Use `DateTimeOffset`, which includes a timezone component. Then, use something client-side like moment.js which supports localizing dates and times.

Comment: I would like to stay with DateTime as far I am passing it to .Net client with models which are used in other places as well

Comment: Frankly, if you care about localization at all, you should *always* be using `DateTimeOffset` everywhere. There's actually not a whole lot of good reason to ever use `DateTime` at all in fact.

Comment: @GrigoryantsArtem that's even more reason to use DateTimeOffset and avoid unspecified offsets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that [kind is lost with the MessagePackProtocol](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp).

> `DateTime` is serialized to MessagePack Timestamp format, it serialize/deserialize UTC and loses `Kind` info.

The note continues by saying we can change that by using the `NativeDateTimeResolver` instead (albeit with some limitations).

> If you use `NativeDateTimeResolver` serialized native `DateTime` binary format and it can keep `Kind` info but cannot communicate other platforms.

As Chris and Panagiotis mention, it's better to use `DateTimeOffset`. The official [Microsoft documentation says this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime):

> DateTimeOffset should be considered the default date and time type for application development.

There is also much useful information on StackOverflow comparing [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried that approach but for some reason it didn't work... Just updated the question regarding to it.

Comment: Does it still not work when you do not include the `StandardResolver` in the list of revolvers?

Answer (score 2):

Here the order of resolvers is important. The problem will be solve if `NativeDateTimeResolver` will be provided before `StandardResolver` like this.

```
.AddMessagePackProtocol(options =>
options.FormatterResolvers = new List<MessagePack.IFormatterResolver>()
{
    NativeDateTimeResolver.Instance,
    StandardResolver.Instance        
})
```