# C# - Consolidate TimeZones across the system

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, timezone

We had an application with some inconsistent Date/Time stamps used. In some places we used UTC time zone and few other places with Central Time Zone.
I'm looking for an approach to consolidate all the Date/Time stamps across application to UTC, and also to support localization of these Time stamps.

Comment: Good luck :-)
Basically, there's no way of knowing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset)

Comment: n.b. Question is different, but answers are very relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you CAN work out which is CET and which is UTC.

Imagine you have the following 3 fields in your database:

```
2018-01-02T12:00:00
2018-01-02T13:00:00
2018-01-02T14:00:00
```

One of them is CET, the other 2 are UTC.