# DateTimeOffset: Is the DateTime the local time, or UTC time?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datetimeoffset

I got pretty much confused today when talking to a colleague, so please excuse me. I have this:

1. date: 2020-04-01 (yyyy-MM-dd)
2. time: 10:00:00
3. timezone: +2

When I return this to my colleague, I do it through an API that returns json, it returns something on the line

```
{
    ...
    "dateTimeOffset": "2020-04-01T10:00:00+02:00"
    ...
}
```

I build my DateTimeOffset like this:

```cs
var utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
string time = "10:00:00";
string timezoneIdentifier = "Romance Standard Time";
var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
 var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezoneIdentifier);
var timespanOffset = zone.GetUtcOffset(utc);

var baseDateTime = date + TimeSpan.Parse(time);
baseDateTime= DateTime.SpecifyKind(baseDateTime, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(baseDateTime, timespanOffset);
```

When he pulls it in, his part converts the time to "12:00:00", that is: it adds the timezone, and it really got me, because I got so confused, because, he wanted me to send him "08:00:00 +2", so it was showing correctly to the end user, but i refused, because my understanding is: the time part is *the local time* and the +2, describes the offset from UTC, and it isn't the other way around: that the time part is UTC and you have to add the offset to get the local time. I can't find it anywhere in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netcore-2.2 other than

> The DateTimeOffset structure includes a DateTime value, together with an Offset property that defines the difference between the current DateTimeOffset instance's date and time and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). Because it exactly defines a date and time relative to UTC, the DateTimeOffset structure does not include a Kind member, as the DateTime structure does

But that is not good enough for me. My brain will not accept it. So:
1. is the time in a DateTimeOffset the local time of a given zone, or
2. is the time the UTC time, and you have to add/substract the offset to get the local time

I know this should be basic stuff, but we have discussed it so much that I dont know what to think anymore.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: See [Wiki ISO 8601 - Time offsets from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC)

Comment: The `DateTime` value is the local value. You can use the `Offset` to calculate UTC from that `DateTime` value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset)

Comment: @HereticMonkey somewhat it does. I actually understand the answer you refer to, but, i dont understand what the date and time represent in a DateTimeOffset. I can see now that the DateTime in a DateTimeOffset has a DateTime. That DateTime is the local value.

Comment: You could solve this problem forever by changing the JSON structure you have agreed upon to use to have two fields, one called "userLocalTime" and one called "userTimeZone" and now there is no ambiguity to have an argument about. Or "userUTCTime" and one called "userTimeZone" and again, no ambiguity to have an argument about. The problem is that you've having an argument, so fix that problem.

Comment: @EricLippert and that is what I want, but I also want to assure that the problem gets solved and for that I need to understand why his Angular frontend is adding the two hours,  so the 12:00:00 is becoming the result, instead of 10:00:00. So I have been confused  if the time in the offset was local time or utc time. I can now see it is local time, as I expected. So now I can use that to 1) fix his code 2) make a more clean api

Comment: @HereticMonkey could you put it in this was: if you remove the +02:00 from 2020-04-01T10:00:00+02:00 you will have the local time?

Comment: Well, now you're adding a serialization step. I was just talking about how the .NET `DateTimeOffset` type works. According to [this dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G3nLQR) it looks like indeed, removing "+02:00" does indeed leave the local time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that is correct. I am. DateTime is the local part of the DateTimeOffset and it looks like the DateTime part is indeed serialized and shown. That must be the correct way of looking at it. There must be some sort of bug in the javascript since it adds the offset to the local part. That is what I find the most strange.

Answer (score 0):

It is local date time +/- offset of local time from UTC offset.

Example: est is 4 hour behind utc

Current est time = 27 March 2024 : 11:23.45.343

Current Utc time = 27 March 2024 : 15:23.45.343

Date time offset column will hold : `2024-03-27 11:23:45.343 -04:00`

Alternatively, you can also put directly in utc  but with zero offset :`2024-03-27 15:23:45.343 +00:00`

You can also prove this fact by
By doing `select ... column_name='2024-03-27 11:23:45.343 -04:00'`

Only the records which compares to above  time will show up.

Example this time: `2024-03-27 15:23:45.343 +00:00` is same as one in the query.

Answer (score 0):

> When he pulls it in, his part converts the time to "12:00:00", that is: it adds the timezone

I don't think so. The date you provided represents `08:00:00` in UTC time, since the time offset is supposed to represent an offset that was *already applied* to the time element. In all likelihood, your colleague is in a time zone where `10:00:00+02:00` (or 8 AM UTC) translates to noon in their local time.

> 1. is the time in a DateTimeOffset the local time of a given zone, or 2. is the time the UTC time, and you have to add/substract the offset to get the local time

Neither. The entire DateTimeOffset doesn't represent a wall-clock time, the way DateTime does--instead it represents a point in time. If you want the time to represent UTC, unambiguously, then make the offset zero. There is nothing explicit in the DateTimeOffset type that says what the time or the offset is meant to represent--only that the two values together represent a specific point in time.

Libraries like Noda Time have specific types to represent a variety of different time concepts. But C#'s DateTimeOffset and DateTime, JavaScript's Date, and the ISO 8601 date representation you're using in your JSON are all ambiguous as to what the Time portion means--nor do they represent an actual "time zone" (which is not the same thing as a time offset).

You and your colleague need to determine what this date and time are actually supposed to represent. If it's a wall-clock date (like the time for an in-person appointment), you need to remove the offset entirely.

```
// Output depends on the time zone of the browser
new Date("2020-04-01T10:00:00+02:00").getHours()

// Output is fixed: `10`
new Date("2020-04-01T10:00:00").getHours()
```

On the other hand, if it's meant to represent a specific point in time (like the time for an online call), it doesn't matter what offset/time you use. If you're doing things right, the browser will translate it to the right time for the user. For example, in my time zone:

```
// '4/1/2020, 6:00:00 AM'
new Date("2020-04-01T10:00:00+02:00").toLocaleString()

// '4/1/2020, 6:00:00 AM'
new Date("2020-04-01T08:00:00+00:00").toLocaleString()
```