# DateTimeOffset.TryParse fails in Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5

I am trying to parse a string using `DateTimeOffset.TryParse`, it succeeds on Windows but fails in Linux:

`DateTimeOffset.TryParse("29.10.2020", out var parsedDate);`

I also tried to parse it using

`DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact("29.10.2020", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate)` but still the bool returned is `false` and the default value `0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00` is being assgined to `parsedDate`.

Any way to do this on Linux?

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: What is your runtime? Mono or .NET Core?

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off using `DateTime.TryParse(...)`?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse a DateTimeOffset when you should be trying to parse a DateTime. Parsing a DateTime from that string should work. A DateTimeOffset also includes a timezone which isn't included in the string you specified.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Do you get an error message? if so, what it is? Do you get the wrong value? if so, what it is? Why are you using `DateTimeOffset` if you only have a date?

Comment: [DateTime vs DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset)

Comment: I don't get an error, it is getting parsed as `0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00`

Comment: @mu88 I am using .NET5

Comment: TryParseExact returns a bool value, if that is false, it means `parsedDate` in your case is default value, so basically the parsing failed, as you observe.

Comment: @ZoharPeled The same method is also parsing string containing time, but there are cases when only dates are passed-in.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I know that, the parsing for `29.10.2020` string works on Windows where my development machine is but fails on Linux where the production app is running.

Comment: @CasperDijkstra There is no error message, the bool returned by `TryParse` is false and the default value `0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00` is assigned to `parsedDate`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled The whole point of Try***() methods is to avoid throwing exceptions. I doubt the OP is getting any info about why the method returns false.

Comment: I was asking because you don't seem to have  an offset component in your string representation, which leads me to think that you might actually need `DateTime` and not `DateTimeOffset`

Comment: @TanveerBadar Yes, I know that. My comment was an attempt to get relevant information from the OP. When I've posted that comment, the question's text was different. Of course I didn't expect `TryParse` to throw an exception, and in fact, any exception thrown from it's equivalent `Parse` method would be just as useless as the `false` returned from `TryParse` - but the point of that comment was to improve the question's quality (and it eventually did - now the question is better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This overload of `TryParse` uses current culture (`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`), so culture is different between your dev machine (windows) and your linux machine. For example:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
DateTimeOffset parsedDate;
bool res = DateTimeOffset.TryParse("29.10.2020", out parsedDate);
Console.WriteLine(res); // false
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru");
res = DateTimeOffset.TryParse("29.10.2020", out parsedDate);
Console.WriteLine(res); // true
```

So you need to use overload which accepts `IFormatProvider` and pass provider there which makes sense for the format in which you store your dates. For example:

```
var cultureOfMyDates = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru");
res = DateTimeOffset.TryParse("29.10.2020", cultureOfMyDates, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
```

Or use `TryParseExact` (your sample with `DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact("29.10.2020", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate)` works fine for me)

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Debian;

```
        DateTimeOffset parsedDate = new DateTimeOffset();
        if(DateTimeOffset.TryParse("29.10.2020".Replace(".", "/"), out parsedDate))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(parsedDate.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse");
        }
```

or as suggested above

```
        DateTimeOffset parsedDate = new DateTimeOffset();
        if(DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact("29.10.2020", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(parsedDate.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse");
        }
```