# How to append current DateTime as a string to a URL in RouteConfig.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

So I have the following route in my `RouteConfig.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Student",
    url: "student",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Student", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Based on this route, I have the following method in my `Home` controller:

```
public ActionResult Student()
{
    return View();
}
```

This simple route when invoked `http://localhost:54326/student` will take me to the Student view. All good till now.

How can I achieve this route: `http://localhost:54326/student/01-28-2021` when I invoke the above route automatically?

Basically, I want to append a string at the end of the original route when it is invoked.

Is there anything I can specify in `RouteConfig` through which I can achieve this?

Comment: why you do not simply use the date as parameter? how many dates you gone make route of?

Comment: I do not want to type the date string. I want the current date to automatically be appended as a string to the url when the original url is invoked. I tried an internal redirect but it is not working.

Comment: Why not return a redirect?

Comment: @CaiusJard I did try that but if I go that way, I get a URL like this: `http://localhost:54326/Home/Student?date=01-30-2021` .I am looking for a URL like: `http://localhost:54326/student/01-28-2021`

Comment: A perfectly valid question, but I would suggest using the date format `2021-01-28` for 2 reasons 1) it is a format that is recognized anywhere in the world 2) it will properly sort chronologically when added to a list (for example, browser history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following route `Student` will allow to append a string at the end of  `http://localhost:54326/student` when it is invoked.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

// It is important that you add this route before the `Default` one.
// Routes are processed in the order they are listed, 
// and we need the new route to take precedence over the default.

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Student",
    url: "Student/{date}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Student", date = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
```

The `Student` action declaration:

```
public ActionResult Student(string date)
{
    //string dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy";
    string dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
    {            
        return RedirectToAction("Student", new { date = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormat) });
    }
    else if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(date, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ReportErrorFormat");
    }
    return View((object)date);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but unfortunately it did not work. The current date is still not being appended to the URL.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: I have changed the `Student` action method to call the `RedirectToActionPermanent()`. Now if `http://localhost:54326/student` is entered it will return `http://localhost:54326/student/01-30-2021` URL.

Comment: How can I change the date format in the URL from `http://localhost:54326/student/01-30-2021` to `http://localhost:54326/student/30-01-2021` ?

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: Some fixes are made in the `Student()` action method to support `dd-MM-yyyy` date format. Select proper the `dateFormat` pattern depend on required date format. Another approach is to change all date-time functions to use current regional settings on the server.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: Some helpful tips for dealing with `DateTime` you can read here: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331189/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331189/6630084)

Comment: Now, nothing is working. It is saying localhost redirected you too many times. Also I keep getting the same value in `date` variable which is: `01-30-2021` and my final URL no matter what I try ends up:`http://localhost:54326/student/01-30-2021`. It seems that in `public ActionResult Student(string date)` the same value is being passed and I am not sure how is that happening since I do not give any value in the URL.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: Try to remove `obj` and `bin` folders. Recompile projects. The IIS is blocking your files from updating. If you will see message that some files in the `bin` folder is locking this is the reason why `nothing is working`.

Comment: Cleared the cache and tried again. It is working as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma: Thank you for feedback. But it looks like there are dark places in the MVC. :)