# convert UTC date string to local dateTime

Tags: c#, .net-5, datetimeoffset

I need to convert UTC dateTime to local I have tried parse but unable to do so?

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UTC DateTime Convertor....!");

        var giveDateTime = "22-06-2021T14:10:45.000";
        var utcGivenDateTime = DateTime.Parse(giveDateTime);???
        var localConvertedTime ???


        Console.WriteLine("Given Date: ", giveDateTime);
        Console.WriteLine("Given UTC DateTime ", utcGivenDateTime);
        Console.WriteLine("Converted Local Time ", localConvertedTime);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You've tagged this post "datetimeoffset", but you're not using that class, which would make this process much easier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset

Comment: Maybe the method [DateTime.ToLocalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime)?

Answer (score 1):

To convert to a local time, you need the timezone you want to convert it to:

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Brazilian Standard Time");
    
var localConvertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcGivenDateTime, timeZoneInfo);
```

Unfortunately, native timezones are currently system specific. If you need to be system agnostic, you might want to look at third party libraries like [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org).