# Content.ReadAsStringAsync() json result adding an extra hour to datetime property

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, httpcontent

Content.ReadAsStringAsync() result adding an extra hour to datetime property.

Here is what i get when call endpoint on postman;

[image]

The ReadAsStringAsync json result return an extra hour to datetime property.

string result = postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

[image]

Why there is an extra hour added to datetime property ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DateTimeOffset` (instantaneous time or absolute time) instead of DateTime.
Read more about in that [SO Anserwer about DateTime vs. DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268167/11473934).

Comment: Why there is no hour added to first record?

Comment: Yes thats strange, in the first record a whole day is added

Comment: Can you provide the code where the deserialization happens

Comment: i have updated the question with more info

Comment: Likely that one date is *during* dst, and one date is outside of dst. In the UK at least dst starts near the end of March so that would line up with your dates (assuming a similar dst setup in your locale). Whole day is a bit weird tho...

Comment: @user1263981 I've added some hints, datetime is tricky ...