# how do I specify the timezone on a DateFormat string?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to specify the timezone on a string that I am passing to `DateFormat.parse`. We're currently using .net framework 2.0. Current code is

```
DateTimeFormatInfo DATE_FORMAT = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
DateTime first = DateTime.Parse("Wed, 31 Oct 2007 8:00:00 -5", DATE_FORMAT);
```

But then when I do `first.ToString("r")`, the result is

```
Wed, 31 Oct 2007 09:00:00 GMT
```

What am I doing wrong? I also tried using `DateTime.SpecifyKind` method to set my DateTime object's Kind to Local, but it seems like you would need to specify the kind as local before you parse the string, if the timezone is part of the string.

My local timezone is EDT, that's what I'm ultimately trying to get this date to.

Edit - our solution:

input :

```
DateTime first = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse("OCT 31, 2007 8:00 AM", DATE_FORMAT), DateTimeKind.Local);
```

output :

```
first.ToLocalTime().ToString("our format")
```

Still haven't found a way to get time zone abbreviation, like 'EDT'.

Comment: For 3.5 see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-fx-35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ToLocalTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx) method before calling `ToString()`.

```
first.ToLocalTime().ToString();
```

Comment: This was part of the answer. I did end up having to use DateFormat.SpecifyKind when I was parsing the original date string. But then we're providing the format in the ToString() when we want to output it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "zz" or "zzz" date formats to give you -5 or -5:00.

Answer (score 1):

When you call first.ToString("**r**"),

Here is what based on MSDN

> Represents a custom date and time
>   format string defined by the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo..::.RFC1123Pattern
>   property. The pattern reflects a
>   defined standard and the property is
>   read-only. Therefore, it is always the
>   same, regardless of the culture used
>   or the format provider supplied. The
>   custom format string is "ddd, dd MMM
>   yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'".

You can pass the defined format information into ToString, try to call this method

DateTime..::.ToString Method (IFormatProvider)

Instead, and pass your DateTimeFormatInfo object.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `DateTimeOffset` struct, I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ParseExact() - you can specify what goes where.

In your case, you can parse it with:

```
        string str = "Wed, 31 Oct 2007 8:00:00 -5";
        string fmt = "ddd, dd MMM yyyy H:mm:ss z";

        DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(str, fmt, null);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
```