# .NET webservice datetime.now - time zone

Tags: .net, datetime, web-services, timezone

I need to return server time from a webservice. I've got the following code:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetDate() As DateTime
        Return DateTime.Now

End Function
```

The code always returns time based on timezone of the connected client (if I change the time zone, the webservice returns updated time, instead of local server time). How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server actually sends the datetime in timezone of its local settings. The client probably interprets it differently (based on its local settings). Its safer to use UTC-times on the server or use DateTimeOffset to provide timezone information.

Answer (score 0):

It's not urgent for the people here so it's useless to flag the question that way.

Take a look at [Creating a DateTime in a specific Time Zone in c# fx 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498) which was the first Google result...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be incorrect in all timezone that don't have UTC offset 0? This would generate DateTime with Kind == Utc and local time. This would be serialized as localtime with utc offset 0. Not great.

Answer (score 0):

you need to always return the utc time. This way you always know its not time zone specific.

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetDate() As DateTime
        Return DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
End Function
```