# How to get a different Timezone in .net with code

Tags: datetime, internationalization, timezone

There must be a simple way to get different timezones with code (ie without changeing your system timezone)
So far you can do something like

```
var timezone =  TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
```

but I cant see any other way to get a different timezone? 
or should I just use TimeSpan? 
Actually it seems like it s a better idea to use TimeZoneInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related answer

[Creating a DateTime in a specific Time Zone in c# fx 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-fx-3-5)

Answer (score 1):

how about using [TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx) ?

This should return an array of all available TimeZone objects in this system.