# Current time of different country-Xamarin

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a test app in Xamarin.forms which will show different time for different countries(India, Uk, USA..).

I tried to use something like this:

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById
```

But doesn't work I get error:

```
Error   2   'System.TimeZoneInfo' does not contain a definition for 'FindSystemTimeZoneById'
```

I have buttons for different countries and as per what user clicks I want to show him the current time of that country. How do I do that?

Comment: If you are doing Xamarin form PCL. You may want to use dependency service.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? :

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(mytime,TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));
```

From this thread?
[Current Time of Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246674/current-time-of-timezone)