# Format String to Datetime with Timezone

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, timezone

I have a `string s = "May 16, 2010 7:20:12 AM CDT` that i want to convert into a DateTime object. In the code below i get a Date format cannot be converted error when attempting to parse the text with a known format.

```
timeStamp = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(timeStamp, "MMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss tt", null);
```

The timezone comes in as CDT UTC... and i think is whats causing the problem or my format?

Comment: How about `var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss tt 'CDT'", null);` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Central Daylight Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Daylight_Time)

Try this:

```
string dts = "May 16, 2010 7:20:12 AM CDT";
DateTime dt = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(dts.Replace("CDT", "-05:00"), "MMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss tt zzz", null);
```

EDIT:

For daylight savings time please consider [DateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isdaylightsavingtime.aspx) and [TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone.aspx)

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: what happens if CDT has daylight savings time and becomes -4?

Comment: where do i find the information about off sets and Timezone, i may also get CST as a timezone and need to replace and handle daylight savings time.

Comment: [Central Time Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone_(North_America)#Central_Daylight_Time), [UTC time offsets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets), [time zone offset](http://www.physics.sfasu.edu/astro/jupiter/offset.html)

Comment: to convert this date to UTC, cant i just dt.ToUniversalTime() ?

Comment: I think you can. Once you convert the string into a DateTime then you should be able to do .ToUniversalTime(). You need to have it in the right format first though (including daylight savings)

Comment: @Greg could you explain your first comment, "daylight savings time becoming -4", i thought CDT was UTC-5.00 and CST was UTC-6.00 ?

Comment: I quite possibly went the wrong way. I live in Sydney and we're UTC +10 normally but in summer UTC+11. I'm not claiming to know the specific timezones, just raising the fact that you can't just use UTC-5, you need to change for daylight savings.

Comment: @Warz: CDT time is -5, please consider reading [CDT wiki document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Daylight_Time)

Comment: Please note that `IsDaylightSavingTime` returns true if the time is daylight time in the `TimeZoneInfo.Local` timezone, **not** the one that the `DateTime` instance you call the method on is set to. How awful is that? If the machine running the app is in UTC, the method always returns `false`

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the DateTime is unambiguously DateTimeKind.Utc. Avoid "GMT", it is ambiguous for daylight saving.

```
    var dt = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    string s = dt.ToLocalTime().ToString("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss tt \"GMT\"zzz");
```

it's gives output : Dec 31, 2010 19:01:01 pm GMT-06:00

For more detail refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-sharp-fx-3-5)

Comment: It's correct to use UTC because it is the international standard, but it GMT is not ambiguous for daylight saving. GMT is always UTC+0. The UK switches to BST during the summer. More info at http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-gmt-and-utc/

Answer (score 0):

I convert my date string with timezone "Thu, 22 Sep 2022 06:38:58 +0200" using "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz":

```
var dateString = "Thu, 22 Sep 2022 06:38:58 +0200";
string[] acceptedDateFormats = { "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz" };

var dateParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, acceptedDateFormats,
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var date);
```

Comment: Problem with this is daylight savings time.   Also with DST, some states/countries don't use DST.