# Storing a UTC time. Displaying it in local time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-mvc-4, client-side

Im writing a mvc4 application that will be used globally. Part of the application is recording when a transaction was added or modified.

So I am saving the transaction datetime as UTC. from the clientside whats my best way to display the date as they are expecting?

Is this a javascript function I should be using or should I be doing something within the view?

Comment: Please define "as they are expecting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, javascript date objects store the time as a number of milliseconds since an epoch UTC (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z). The simplest way to transfer time is using that number, so:

```
// 2012-09-16T10:30:00.000Z
var ms = 1347791400000;

// Create a new date object using UTC milliseconds
var d = new Date(ms);

alert(d); // Shows local time equivalent, e.g. 2012-09-16T20:30:00GMT+1000
```

Alternatively, you can pass a UTC timestamp, split it into its components and convert it to a date object using [Date.UTC](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.4.3). Note that months are zero based so one must be subtracted from the calendar month number.

To get the UTC millisecond value for a local time, use [Date.prototype.getTime](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.9). For the example above:

```
alert(d.getTime()); // 1347791400000
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your preference. If you have user time zone on the server side, stored in the database, the simplest way is to use `DateTimeOffset`.

Example: [Creating a DateTime in a specific Time Zone in c# fx 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-sharp-fx-3-5).

Alternatively, use [JavaScript getTimezoneOffset() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp), set cookie and read it on server. Also you can use many client libs, especially if you use client templating.