# Convert some local time to UTC in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying do to something like this:

On a client side I have datepicker for selecting date, drop down for selecting an hour, and drop down with time zones for selecting user time zone.

I am sending this info to server. On a server side, I want to accomplish this:

Take date and time values, and check what is the value of time zone.
If it is for example "UTC+1" (or any other +- value of UTC time), convert that into UTC, before saving.

What I am not sure how to do it is: What value should I send from client as time zone information so server can detect it is a for example UTC+1.

I saw examples like this:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
```

On how to find out what is the time zone by its id, but I cannot do something like this:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC+1");
```

Because, I get an exception, of course:

> Additional information: The time zone ID 'UTC+1' was not found on the
>   local computer.

Does someone know what is Id for all UTC+-someNumber, or there is a way to detect timezone from UTC string in some different way?

Did someone had experience whit this kind of a conversion?

Comment: You can get *all the time zones about which information is available on the local system* by calling `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` and check their `BaseUtcOffset`. Besides that, it might be simpler to calculate the UTC time on the client side, before sending it to the server.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember the only way to work with the timezones is by the full name that is available in your OS.

You can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149346/what-value-should-i-pass-into-timezoneinfo-findsystemtimezonebyidstring).

A list from MSDN is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms912391(v=winembedded.11).aspx).

So there seems to be no easy way to convert strings like "UTC+1", unless you create a mapping to the ones that are supported by framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone()`:

```
DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo targetTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("MyId", TimeSpan.FromHours(1), "Somewhere", "Somewhere");
DateTime targetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcTime, targetTimeZone);
```

or you can use `DateTimeOffset`, or `DateTime.AddHours(1)`:

```
var datetimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(yourDateTime, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
var otherDatetime = yourDateTime.AddHours(1);
```