# C# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime incorrect result

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to convert time between two timezones, and found out an hour difference between US Eastern Standard Time to Western European Time
Supposedly, USA Eastern Standard Time (EST) 2018 Jun-18 1PM should be Western European Time (WET) same day 6PM, but the result from c# ConvertTime is 7PM, I think I missed something for the daylight setting?
Anyway, here's the code:

```
var str = "2018-07-09T13:00:00";
var dt = Convert.ToDateTime(str);
var SourceZoneValue = "Eastern Standard Time";
var DestinationZoneValue = "W. Europe Standard Time";


TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(SourceZoneValue);
TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(DestinationZoneValue);

DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dt, sourceTimeZone, destinationTimeZone);
Console.WriteLine(localTime);
```

The outcome is 7PM instead 6PM, any idea? tks

Comment: @dasblinkenlight DateTime, it's the first parameter required by the method. I suggest using `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` before converting to make sure it's returning the right timezone.

Comment: sorry guys, my fault, I updated my code

Comment: Keep in mind that we are currently in Daylight saving, so EST != EDT.

Comment: Does "Eastern Standard Time\Dynamic DST" return the same value? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149346/what-value-should-i-pass-into-timezoneinfo-findsystemtimezonebyidstring

Comment: I get 6PM for "US/Eastern" and "Europe/Lisbon" ([demo](https://ideone.com/NOpp9F)).

Comment: so I should manually set SourceZoneValue  = "Eastern Standard Time\Dynamic DST" in this case? and write a method to determine whether it is a daylight zone or not? or there's some class to help? tks

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert from *Eastern Standard Time* to *W. Europe Standard Time*, say from *New York* to *Amsterdam*.

*New York* time zone is -5 GMT, and *Amsterdam* time zone is +1 GMT:

[image]

- *New York* Daylight saving started 11 March 2018 and will end on 4 November 2018.
- *Amsterdam* Daylight saving started 25 March 2018 and will end on 28 October 2018.

Your date is 18 June, so daylight saving does not affect the time difference, I would say 7 PM is the correct result.

---

Maybe `W. Europe Standard Time` is not the correct time zone that you are looking for? For example, for the UK time:

```
var britishZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
```