# The time zone id 'Russia TZ 8 Standard Time was not found on the local computer when converting from one time zone to another

Tags: c#, timezone

When I use

> ReadOnlyCollection timeZones =
> TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

I get a list of timezones and it contains this timezone:

> timeZone.DisplayName = (UTC+09:00) Yakutsk
>
> timeZone.StandardName = Russia TZ 8 Standard Time
> ...

but I think timeZone.StandardName should be:

> Yakutsk Standard Time

to perform the transition from one time zone to another. I use:

> TimeZoneInfo timeInfo =
> TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone.StandardName);

and the following error occurs:

> the time zone id 'Russia TZ 8 Standard Time was not found on the local
> computer

Please someone help me with…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What value should I pass into TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(String)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149346/what-value-should-i-pass-into-timezoneinfo-findsystemtimezonebyidstring)

Comment: Lookup NodaTime

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the ID of the time zone, use the `Id` property, not the `StandardName` property.  After all, the method is called `FindSystemTimeZoneById`, not `FindSystemTimeZoneByStandardName`.

To elaborate further, the `Id` property returns a string that uniquely identifies the time zone and is not affected by localization (language, culture, etc.).  The `DisplayName`, `StandardName`, and `DaylightName` properties return strings that are intended to be human readable and *are* affected by localization.  In modern .NET 6, that localization is `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`.  In prior incantations such as .NET Framework on Windows, that culture was determined by the operating system's default language setting.  Although *some* time zones may have had their `StandardName` and `Id` properties match for US-English, this was never guaranteed nor universally applicable for all time zones or all languages/cultures.