# How to preserve timezone when deserializing DateTime using JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, json.net, deserialization

I'm parsing some JSON in C# using JSON.NET.  One of the fields in the JSON is a date/time, like this:

```
{
    "theTime":"2014-11-20T07:15:11-0500",
    // ... a lot more fields ...
}
```

Note that the time part is  07:15:11 (TZ of GMT-5 hrs)

I parse the JSON from a stream like this:

```
 using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(rcvdStream))
 {
     JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);
     JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
     JObject data = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(reader);
     //...
  }
```

Then access the time:

```
DateTime theTime = (DateTime)data["theTime"];
```

However, this gives me this DateTime object:

```
{20/11/2014 12:15:11}
Date: {20/11/2014 00:00:00}
Day: 20
DayOfWeek: Thursday
DayOfYear: 324
Hour: 12
Kind: Local
Millisecond: 0
Minute: 15
Month: 11
Second: 11
Ticks: 635520825110000000
TimeOfDay: {12:15:11}
Year: 2014
```

I need to know the original local time and tz offset, but I seem to have lost that information in the deserialization process, and it is giving me the time in what I presume is my local time (I'm in the UK, so currently at GMT+0).

Is there a way for me to preserve the timezone information when deserializing?

EDIT: added more detail about how I'm deserializing.

Comment: How are you creating your `serializer` object?

Comment: Have you tried deserializing/casting it to a DateTimeOffset rather than a DateTime?

Comment: I've updated the post to show how I'm creating the serializer object.

Comment: I would recommend converting to UTC, sending/receiving in UTC, and converting to local time on the client side for display purposes.

Comment: Casting to a DateTimeOffset is still wrong - the time is 12:15 and offset is 00:00.

Comment: I have no control over the source JSON, so I can't change it to be UTC.

Comment: Note that the post suggested as the duplicate of this one, while it is originally asking about timezone codes, has the answer you're looking for: your string has the timezone offset, and it shows how to correctly parse a `DateTime` containing a timezone offset.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate question.  The other answer linked to is about parsing DateTime but not from the Json deserializer.  For that to be useful he'd have to change the deserializer to just return the date as a string, and then parse the string wherever needed. `serializer.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;`

Comment: Also mentioning that question is not duplicate. The other question is about timezone abbreviations like "CET", this one is about numeric timezones, like "+01:00". Also note that many know JSON.NET as Newtonsoft.Json. and that it handles timezones "Z" and "+00:00" differently (only "Z" is treated as actual UTC!)

Comment: The question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-sharp, but not currently specified question

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would use [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) for this instead. `DateTime` doesn't have any useful time zone information associated with it.

You can deserialize to `DateTimeOffset` instead by changing `serializer.DateParseHandling`:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset;

JObject data = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(reader);

var offset = (DateTimeOffset)data["theTime"];

Console.WriteLine(offset.Offset);    // -5:00:00
Console.WriteLine(offset.DateTime);  // 11/20/2014 7:15:11 AM
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/I9UAuC