# C# Issue in reading date value form json data

Tags: c#, json, parsing

when I read data value it changed.
i need this string value 2018-03-27T20:00:00+11:00 but getting 3/27/2018 2:00:00 PM in mydate string.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string data="{\"start_date\":\"2018-03-27T20:00:00+11:00\",\"end_date\":null,\"on_sale_date\":\"2017-11-24T08:55:00+11:00\",\"date_confirmed\":true}";
        JObject pdata = JObject.Parse(data);
        string mydate = pdata["start_date"].ToString();

    }
```

Comment: Due to timezone differences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preserve timezone when deserializing DateTime using JSON.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043220/how-to-preserve-timezone-when-deserializing-datetime-using-json-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible to disable the `DateParseHandling` with `JObject.Parse`.
You can use the `DeserializeObject` methode from `JsonConvert` and disable the `DateParseHandling`:

```
string data = "{\"start_date\":\"2018-03-27T20:00:00+11:00\",\"end_date\":null,\"on_sale_date\":\"2017-11-24T08:55:00+11:00\",\"date_confirmed\":true}";
dynamic pdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
});
string mydate = pdata.start_date;
Console.WriteLine(mydate);
```