# Webservice - How to pass timezone info in a datetime element

Tags: c#, web-services, datetime, soap, wsdl

I've been given a wsdl and I have to create a web service following its specs; I'm using visual studio 2010.
Among the others there is also the definition of this complex type:

```
    <xsd:complexType name="Person">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="surname" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="birthDate" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Using VS I got the following cs (I don't recall exaclty how I did but I followed instructions found on the web):

```
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://XXX/Submitter/")]
    public partial class Person {
        private string surnameField;
        private string nameField;
        private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> birthDateField;

        /// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string surname {
            get {
                return this.surnameField;
            }
            set {
                this.surnameField = value;
            }
        }
        /// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string name {
            get {
                return this.nameField;
            }
            set {
                this.nameField = value;
            }
        }
        /// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true)]
        public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> birthDate {
            get {
                return this.birthDateField;
            }
            set {
                this.birthDateField = value;
            }
        }
```

And everything is correct: it compiles, runs and gives expected result; the only problem is that the other party that gave me the wsdl, when calling my web service, expects to get the birthdate field as

```
2013-02-15T17:28:00+01:00
```

with the time zone information, while the result they receive is like

```
2015-11-17T18:30:11
```

without timezone.

My problem is that I have a `DateTime?` type and that is the one I pass to my object instantiated from the class; should I override the serialization or there is another most common solution?
Thanks

Comment: DateTime is fine. But it doesn't contain Timezone info, so you'll have to store that separately. You might want to check the DateTimeOffset object.  You'll have to answer a few questions for yourself to properly send the right info...  What is the timezone relative to? (i.e. The client? Your server? Some other location?) And what's the time zone of the date you're submitting (if it's not UTC), because you'll need to convert.

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey My problem is not how to retrieve the timezone, moreover since it would be an ad hoc integration specific for only one customer here in Italy and he time zone would be the one relative to client and server in the same building (hospital environment). My current problem is how to pass this information when the wsdl says it has to be a datetime, a datatype not containing timezone info; I'm not even sure I can ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's a significant mismatch between XSD and what .NET supports in SOAP web services.

.NET only has two types for this sort of information - `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`.  Technically, it would be best if `xs:datetime` mapped to `DateTimeOffset`, but that's not how it works.  Instead `xs:datetime` is mapped to `DateTime`, and relies heavily on the `Kind` property of the value to determine how it's serialized.

- When the `DateTime.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, no offset information is passed.
- When the `DateTime.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Utc`, then `Z` is passed, which is the same as `+00:00`.
- When the `DateTime.Kind` is `DateTimeKind.Local`, then the local offset corresponding to the given date is passed.

You can apply a kind by using `DateTime.SpecifyKind`, or if you want to convert the value in the process, you can use `.ToUniversalTime()` or `.ToLocalTime()`.  Or, if you know the values belong to a specific time zone, you can use the conversion methods from the `TimeZoneInfo` object.  As long as the resulting kind is anything other than `Unspecified` it will include an offset.

Unfortunately, there is no option to specify an *arbitrary* offset.  That would require the `DateTimeOffset` type, which isn't supported in SOAP services.

Also, consider that really the `xs:datetime` type is the wrong type for a birth date.  It should be using `xs:date`, which is *just* a date, such as `"2013-02-15"`.  There's currently no type that supports this in .NET, though there is one coming soon, as `Date` in the System.Time package in [corefxlab](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab) package.  This will be useful for scenarios like these, but it remains to be seen if we can go back and fix the SOAP serializers to use them.

Really, the best idea is to not use XML and SOAP.  Design your web services around JSON and REST instead.  There you can have full control over things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Jon Skeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246529/1698964). He suggests a structure like this:

```
public struct DateTimeWithZone
{
    private readonly DateTime utcDateTime;
    private readonly TimeZoneInfo timeZone;

    public DateTimeWithZone(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime, timeZone); 
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
    }

    public DateTime UniversalTime { get { return utcDateTime; } }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone { get { return timeZone; } }

    public DateTime LocalTime
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDateTime, timeZone); 
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: My problem is not to get the correct time related to the timezone, but rather to put those info (timezone) in the datetime data I'm passing when the webservice is called. For what I've understood this solution is just adjusting the datetime using tiemezoneinfo. In any case tomorrow morning I'll give a try, when the other party will be present :)