# Getting date in correct formatted for with proper timezone, among list of strings in an a array

Tags: c#, datetime, data-conversion

I have a set of array.

```
//this is not hard corded, some times array will have multiple no.of strings in date format.
["vishnu","2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z","1992","banglore"]
```

I have an array of strings, among these strings there is one string which is in date format.

I need to do a `foreach` and need to check which string is in the date format.
If we got the date string `"2016-08-30T18:30:00.000Z"` I need to convert it to basic date format but in correct timezone, here the date is `2016-08-31` but what I need as out put is

```
["vishnu","31/8/2016","1992","banglore"]
```

not

```
//check the difference in date!
["vishnu","30/8/2016","1992","banglore"]
```

the aim is from the array, if `string` is in date string format, convert it.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{                        
    string inputString = "2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z";
    DateTime enteredDate = DateTime.Parse(inputString);
    Console.WriteLine(enteredDate);
    DateTime dDate;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(inputString, out dDate))
    {
        DateTime dtx = enteredDate.ToLocalTime();
        String.Format("{0:d/MM/yyyy}", dDate); 
        Console.WriteLine(dtx);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid"); // <-- Control flow goes here
    }

   // DateTime dt = convertedDate.ToLocalTime();
}
```

Comment: Could you please post some code that you already have trying to solve this problem.

Comment: http://rextester.com/CQCVP23274  
i needed output as 1/9/2016

Comment: do I get it right, that you need the date to be corrected for the current time zone ?=!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     DateTime dDate;
```

do this  operation iside foreach

```
        if (DateTime.TryParse(answerString, out dDate))
        {
            DateTime enteredDate = DateTime.Parse(answerString);
            var Date = enteredDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            answerString = Date;
           Console.WriteLine(answerString);
        }
    else{
    //operation
        }
```

thanks to mong zhu

Answer (score 1):

If you need to correct the `DateTime` for the time zone, you can use `TimezoneInfo.ConvertTime()`:

```
string inputString = "2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z";

DateTime dDate;

if (DateTime.TryParse(inputString, out dDate))
{
    DateTime correctedDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local);

    // write this here back into the array using your format
    Console.WriteLine(correctedDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid"); // <-- Control flow goes here
}
```

For further reference check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-sharp-fx-3-5). This answer is inspired by it to use `TimeZoneInfo`.

Comment: could you just make it like, converting into gmt+5.30 time format?

Comment: is it always +5.30 ? are the strings in your array always from the same time zone? Have you tried also the answer by @Enigmativity?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `DateTimeOffset` rather than `DateTime` as it is built to handle time zones.

Here's the code:

```
string inputString = "2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z";

DateTimeOffset enteredDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(inputString);
Console.WriteLine(enteredDate);

DateTimeOffset dtx = enteredDate.ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine(dtx);
```

This produces the following for me in GMT+09:30:

```
2016/08/31 18:30:00 +00:00
2016/09/01 04:00:00 +09:30
```

To get it in Indian time try this:

```
DateTimeOffset dtx = enteredDate.ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(5.5));
Console.WriteLine(dtx);
```

I get `2016/09/01 00:00:00 +05:30` now.

Comment: Although the answer youre giving is would work, should the users application get shipped to another country \ time zone then the hours you're entering would be totally out.  For instance BST, GMT and UTC are all times referenced within the UK, or if the user is in a CET time zone and then moves to a PT time zone all figures would be out.

Comment: @SimonPrice - Yes, that's why I showed the `.ToLocalTime()` call. It would work perfectly fine in any user's time zone. So, the OP could simply use that without the `.ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(5.5))`.

Comment: My Apologies, I missed that line