# Get UTC equivalent of static DateTime

Tags: c#

What i need to do here is simple but for some reason i'm just drawing a blank on this and need some assurance on how to do it correctly.

I'm trying to determine the UTC equivalent of 5AM Pacific Time tomorrow. I'm trying to do this without relying on the server time as i have no way of knowing what time zone this is.

I just need a sanity check on the following. Is this the best way to do this? Am i going to run into issues with the server time being off? Is this going to give me a accurate representation of 5am tomorrow UTC?

```
DateTime datetime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day, 5, 0, 0); //5AM tomorrow
TimeZoneInfo pstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
DateTime pstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(datetime, pstZone);
```

TIA

Comment: use `UtcNow` instead of `Now`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-sharp-fx-3-5

Comment: What do you mean by tomorrow? Tomorrow in which time zone?

Comment: Your `DateTime.Now` values for Year, Month, and Days are all contingent on the time zone of the machine that the code is executing on. There's all sorts of wrapping that can occur trying to find "tomorrow".

Comment: @AdamBrown Tomorrow PST time

Comment: Okay. I see. I'll answer.

Comment: I am not seeing how my question is a duplicate of the one mentioned. My question involved a hard time i am trying to determine as apposed to reading a server time for a specified time zone... I would hardly call that "exact duplicate"

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually missing some details. Basically, the method is:

1. Take now in UTC
2. Convert it to pst.
3. Take "today"
4. Add a day to get "tomorrow"
5. Add 5 hours to get 5am.
6. Convert back to UTC

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
     TimeZoneInfo pstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
     var pstNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcNow, pstZone);

     DateTime targetPstTime = pstNow.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(5);

     DateTime utcAnswer = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(targetPstTime, pstZone);

     Console.WriteLine(utcAnswer);
     Console.ReadKey();

 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i needed! I appreciate you patience with me.