# set global timezone in .net core

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, .net-core, timezone

In .Net Core 2 -

Is there a way to set the application's timezone globally so that whenever I request for `DateTime.Now` I'll get the current time for a timezone I want (lets say GMT+3) instead of the time of the server where the application is hosted?

I figured a good place to have a configuration providing this would be the Startup.cs file, but my search queries gets me nowhere with this.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 12):

You can use TimeZoneInfo for this

```
DateTime eastern = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.Now, "Eastern Standard Time");
```

Replace with the desired time zone.

Comment: Be careful with cross-platform issues: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/cross-platform-time-zones-with-net-core/

Answer (score 5):

No.

`DateTime.Now` always returns the time in the system's local time zone.