# Is there a ZonedDateTime (Java) in .Net?

Tags: c#, timezone, datetimeoffset

The best equivalent I've found is the combination of a DateTimeOffset + TimeZoneInfo. Is that the best approach, create a structure that contains both of these classes and insure they stay consistent?

Comment: [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) should look familiar to you. It started as a port of Joda Time, which was the basis for the overhaul of Java's temporal types that include ZonedDateTime.

Comment: Is that you need? https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.ZonedDateTime.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a DateTime in a specific Time Zone in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Unfortunately no. I need for example to be able to set to a datetime in MountaintTime, and the offset will change depending on if we're in standard or daylight time. NodaTime may be the answer although it feels like overkill for our need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a built-in type similar to `ZonedDateTime` in the .NET base class library.

As others pointed out, if you're looking for a temporal model similar to Java's Joda Time or `java.time`, then consider using [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org).  It has a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://nodatime.org/api/NodaTime.ZonedDateTime.html) structure.

If you don't want to use Noda Time, and you really need a single object containing date time offset and time zone, then your suggested approach of a struct with `DateTimeOffset` and `TimeZoneInfo` fields makes sense.  Here are some additional tips:

- It's important you design this as an *immutable* struct, in otherwords - take input only from the constructor.  Expose only property getters over the fields.  Don't expose the fields directly, and don't provide setters on the properties.
- Be aware of how you want to handle situations where the offset of a `DateTimeOffset` is *not* the correct offset for the given time zone.  You may want to adjust it, or you may want to throw an exception.
- You may need to provide custom serialization for your struct, and you may need to deconstruct it if saving to a database.  In either scenario, keep only the string `Id` of the `TimeZoneInfo` component.  Don't try to serialize or store the entire object.

That said - you might want to reconsider if you need such an object.  In many cases, simply using the `DateTimeOffset` and `TimeZoneInfo` separately are sufficient.