# UTC offset time that will evaluate to a specific local time

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

I need to produce a UTC time that is relevant to a specific location anywhere in the world such that when the client translates the time locally it will produce the **expected time**.

Let me be more concrete.

The user is in Paris, +1 UTC offset.

I need to ensure the **time** displayed by the UX is `0300`.

But what I send in the JSON payload to be the UTC offset that will produce that.

So, in this case, it needs to be `0200` in the UTC time.

This is what I've got started, but I'm pretty green to date time operations like this, so I'm not quite sure I'm even building the foundation right.

```
public static DateTime ToUtcOffsetFromBaseTime(this NextRunTime nextRunTime, Base? staffBase)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(staffBase, nameof(staffBase));

    var instant = DateTime.UtcNow.ToInstant();
    var baseOffset = staffBase.OffsetAsOf(instant);

    if (baseOffset.HasValue)
    {
        // get the NOW local offset time
        var baseOffsetInstant = instant.WithOffset(baseOffset.Value);

        // set the local time to the next run time
        baseOffsetInstant.PlusHours(baseOffsetInstant.Hour - nextRunTime.Hour);
        baseOffsetInstant.PlusMinutes(baseOffsetInstant.Minute - nextRunTime.Minute);

        // offset it to the relative UTC time and return
        return baseOffsetInstant.ToDateTimeOffset().UtcDateTime;
    }

    throw new Exception($"The base offset for {staffBase.BaseCode} could not be found for the date/time {instant}.");
}
```

The `NextRunTime` has the hour and minute that it needs to represent locally. So you might have an `Hour` of `3` and a `Minute` of `0` such that it needs to represent `0300` local time when the client converts it to local time. Or, you might have something like `9` for the `Hour` and `45` for the `Minute`.

```
public class NextRunTime
{
    public required int Hour { get; set; }

    public required int Minute { get; set; }

    public required string Type { get; set; }
}
```

But, I'm not sure where to go from here honestly, and I'm not sure what I've even started with is right.

Comment: Perhaps [Creating a datetime in a specific time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246498/creating-a-datetime-in-a-specific-time-zone-in-c-sharp) might be of help? If you want to represent the "time of day" you might want [TimeOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-8.0).

Comment: Thanks @JonasH, I'll look into your suggestions.

Comment: DateTimeOffset which contains timezone info is the recommended datatype to use.

Comment: I think you're really looking for `DateTimeZone.MapLocal` - which will take account of time zone transitions, alert you to skipped and ambiguous times etc, rather than you just assuming a single UTC offset is going to be correct for a time zone for a whole chunk of time. You don't need to do any of the low level stuff. (I'd also advise against mixing Noda Time and the BCL types if you possibly can - if you stick to just Noda Time types you're likely to have a better time.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, your comment helped me think it through some more based off of the data we have stored in the `Base` and its offsets. I've posted my solution below. If you have the time to review it and let me know your thoughts, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it worked out. In the end my original solution wasn't too far off.

```
public static DateTime ToUtcOffsetFromBaseTime(this NextRunTime nextRunTime, Base? staffBase, DateTime? asOf)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(staffBase, nameof(staffBase));

    var instant = (asOf ?? DateTime.UtcNow).ToInstant();
    var offset = staffBase.OffsetAsOf(instant);

    if (offset.HasValue)
    {
        // get the NOW local offset time
        var offsetInstant = instant.WithOffset(offset.Value);

        // set the local time to the next run time
        var nextRunTimeOffsetInstant = offsetInstant
            .PlusHours(nextRunTime.Hour - offsetInstant.Hour)
            .PlusMinutes(nextRunTime.Minute - offsetInstant.Minute)
            .PlusSeconds(0 - offsetInstant.Second)
            .PlusMilliseconds(0 - offsetInstant.Millisecond)
            .PlusNanoseconds(0 - offsetInstant.NanosecondOfSecond);

        // offset it to the relative UTC time and return
        var nextRunTimeUtcOffsetInstant = nextRunTimeOffsetInstant.WithOffset(Offset.FromHours(0));

        return nextRunTimeUtcOffsetInstant.LocalDateTime.InUtc().ToDateTimeUtc();
    }

    throw new Exception($"The base offset for {staffBase.BaseCode} could not be found for the date/time {instant}.");
}
```

The basic flow can be described like this:

- Take a moment in time (in UTC) and offset that using the stored `Base` offset from the database
- Set the time components based off of the configured next run time (in local base time)
- Convert that local base time to its relative UTC time
- Return that to the client

I added the `asOf` for unit testing.

The reason this flow is so important is because the relative UTC time for each local location is going to be different.

If anybody knows a cleaner way of doing the same thing, let me know.

Here is a unit test that validates it.

```
[Fact]
public void ToUtcOffsetFromBaseTime()
{
    // setup
    var nextRunTime = new NextRunTime
    {
        Hour = 3,
        Minute = 0,
        Type = "STT"
    };

    var staffBase = new Base
    {
        BaseCode = "BAS",
        UTCOffsets =
        [
            new DSTOffset
            {
                TimezoneStart = Instant.FromUtc(2024, 3, 10, 15, 0),
                TimezoneEnd = Instant.FromUtc(2024, 11, 3, 14, 59, 59),
                UTCOffset = Offset.FromHours(-6)
            },
            new DSTOffset
            {
                TimezoneStart = Instant.FromUtc(2024, 11, 3, 15, 0),
                TimezoneEnd = Instant.FromUtc(2025, 3, 9, 14, 59, 59),
                UTCOffset = Offset.FromHours(-7)
            }
        ]
    };

    var asOf = new DateTime(2024, 3, 12, 2, 21, 45, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    // test
    var result = nextRunTime.ToUtcOffsetFromBaseTime(staffBase, asOf);

    Assert.Equal(9, result.Hour);
    Assert.Equal(0, result.Minute);
    Assert.Equal(0, result.Second);
    Assert.Equal(0, result.Millisecond);
    Assert.Equal(0, result.Nanosecond);
}
```

Comment: Fundamentally, it looks like you're still making an assumption that the offset at some other instant in time will be the same as the offset now. (I'm also finding it hard to check which types are involved, due to the use of `offsetInstant` which isn't a concept in Noda Time...) I'd still recommend using `DateTimeZone.MapLocal` if you possibly can.