# DateTime.Parse for pubDate in RSS Feeds

Tags: c#, datetime, rss, parsing

I'm trying to pull a DateTime object from RSS feeds in C# and DateTime.Parse(string) was working fine for the BBC rss feed which has a format like: Thu, 24 Sep 2009 13:08:30 GMT

But when I try and use that for Engadget's feed which has a date format like Thu, 24 Sep 2009 17:04:00 EST throws a FormatException.

Is there something straight forward that I'm missing here?

Comment: That date format may very well be one of the worst ones I know.

Comment: Fredrik, which one (of the 2 examples) ?

Comment: @Henk: well, both but especially the one found in many RSS feeds with those special time zones.

Answer (score 5):

DateTime.Parse doesn't understand EST.  It only understands GMT on the end of the string.

Standard Date and Time Format Strings Link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Here's an SO link to help... EST and such are not recognized.  You will have to convert them to the time offsets:

[Parse DateTime with time zone of form PST/CEST/UTC/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc)

Answer (score 5):

Parsing dates in RSS feeds is VERY frustrating.  I came across a fantastic free library called the [Argotic Syndication Framework on CodePlex](http://argotic.codeplex.com/).  It works like a champ and also supports ATOM feeds.  Returns a nice little dataset from a feed, including a standard date.

Comment: Available as a NuGet package as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote this, someone else might find it useful.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts c# DateTime object into pubdate format for RSS
/// Desired format: Mon, 28 Mar 2011 02:51:23 -0700
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Date">DateTime object to parse</param>
/// <returns>Formatted string in correct format</returns>
public static string PubDate(DateTime Date)
{
    string ReturnString = Date.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0,3) + ", ";
    ReturnString += Date.Day + " ";
    ReturnString += CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(Date.Month) + " ";
    ReturnString += Date.Year + " ";
    ReturnString += Date.TimeOfDay + " -0700";

    return ReturnString;
}
```