# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime ParseExact

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to parse a date in c# and have the following line of code

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DateSelected, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Culture)
```

when I debug DateSelected is coming in as "Tue Feb 16 12:36:41 CST 2010" but I get an expection saying "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: What is "Culture" ? It should be an English speaking culture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241789/parse-datetime-with-timezone-of-form-pst-cest-utc-etc/241885#241885), zone abbreviations are not recognized. Try this:

```
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "Tue Feb 16 12:36:41 CST 2010".Replace("CST", "+02:00"), 
    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
    new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

This links can also be useful:

- [Time zone abbreviations](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/)
- [TZ4Net Library](http://www.babiej.demon.nl/Tz4Net/main.htm)
- [Time Zones in the .NET Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2006/04/03/567119.aspx)

Comment: This could be pretty clean, if there was a comprehensive list of timezeones.

Comment: How can I convert it to year-month-day ---> 2011-06-20.
I don't need the additional info like CST Tue Feb and hours.
can someone please?