# Correct parsing of datetime in string format to DateTime object with .NET

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime ParseExact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186861/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-parseexact)

I have a datetime string input to my application, the value is

```
11/22/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

when i call `Convert.ChangeType(abovedate,typeof(DateTime));`

I get a Formatexception, is there a way like a regex to find the format of the datetime and then create a dateformat and then apply so that i get back the correct datetime after parsing the string back to DateTime.

Comment: asked and answered trillions of times here in StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186861/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-parseexact

Comment: For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277320/datetime-string-parsing

Comment: Further to the answers below (+1 btw) you may wish to take into account the culture sensitive nature of date format i.e. your example is US format, which would be incorrect for Europe

Comment: @liho1eye: That's cheating the banning of *lmgtfy* links in comments ;)

Comment: @Otiel I had no idea it is banned. I shortened it because it is prettier that way.

Comment: closing this as exact duplicate is absolutely ridiculous.. some users have understood the question and others have just given some namesake replies and url references..

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you need is `DateTime.Parse`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What about using DateTime.Parse Method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Comment: I wanted to find the format in the string and then apply that as a format so that i can getback the datetime object without `FormatException`.

Answer (score 1):

The method you're after is `DateTime.TryParseExact`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) method or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your string looks fine. However, you can use TryParse, and then if it's successful (true), pass the parsed variable to a dateTime var.

DateTime dateTime;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeToValidate, out dateTime))