# C# parse regional date time strings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to make a small application for a project in which clients from across the world can use. The problem I am having is that the back-end is setup using XML files that gets generated and uploaded to a shared network and in these XML files I store a date time variable that says when a particular task started and finished. The program crashes at certain load intervals with a format exception and after some research I found out that I need to setup a regional date time parser.

The question that I have is how can I convert the time in the XML file, whether it's using US, AU, or UK regional settings, and have it use the client's local settings. This is being done using VS C# 2005 and the .NET 3.5 framework.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you post your current date parsing code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The backends *should* be writing in a standard format. The XML shouldn't just use the local date format - that way madness lies. The main point of XML is to be an interchange format for *computers*, not for *humans*. Unless you're formatting something for *human* consumption, you shouldn't be using local variation.

So either use a specific format everywhere, specifying CultureInfo.InvariantCulture when formatting, or use `dt.ToString("o")` or another of the culture-invariant format strings.

If you're just talking about a point in time (i.e. the local time doesn't matter, just the global instant) you should *also* make sure you use a consistent time zone, where UTC is the obvious choice. For example, use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`.

Once you've got the *generation* code doing sensible things, *consuming* it should be very straightforward.

If, however, you don't have the luxury of changing the generation code, you *may* have to resort to passing the right `CultureInfo` into `DateTime.TryParseExact`. However, this means that you'll need to know the culture used to create the file. If the files are being generated in a culture-sensitive way and you don't know which culture they're using, you're basically stuffed. For example, 03/05/2010 could mean March 5th 2010 or May 3rd 2010. Without any more information, you have no way of deciding which to use.

Answer (score 1):

Regional settings implies format. This is **not** your main concern. Format is simple (use a `DateTime.Parse` or `.ParseExact`. **Time zones should be your primary concern**.

Please refer to [How to convert string to local Date Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873281/how-to-convert-string-to-local-date-time/3873325#3873325)

Comment: Time zones are *also* simple if you only care about an instant in time, which it sounds like is the case here (representing when a task started or finished) - just represent everything as UTC.

Comment: Absolutely, Jon. Utc is the way to go. My point is to cause the user to consider time zones as being more of a problem that format. There's plenty built into .NET to consume/output different formats, but if you don't store time zone data (or store dates as UTC) then you aren't going to be able to be accurate.